# How do I make JavaScript Object using a variable String to define the class name?

Tags: javascript, oop

Here's what I'm trying to do -- this is pseudo code and doesn't work. Does anyone know how to accomplish this for real:

```
// Define the class
MyClass = Class.extend({});

// Store the class name in a string
var classNameString = 'MyClass';

// Instantiate the object using the class name string
var myObject = new classNameString();
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Would it work if you did something like this:

```
var myObject = window[classNameString];
```

..?

Comment: That worked. peirix you are awesome. You think it's cross-browser compatible?

Comment: Think you meant `window[classNameString]` (no quotes). Breaks as soon as `MyClass` is moved to a lower (i.e. `function`) scope. @kirk: yes this is cross-browser.

Comment: How do you pass arguments to the constructor using this method?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon In that case you'd have to use `window[classNameString](args)`. But as Crescent Fresh mentions, be careful, as this might break in some cases.

Comment: @peirix That's great! Any idea if I can do that with classes loaded with requirejs??

Comment: @Reno I don't know. I haven't tried, but that should be easy to try out. I would guess that there would be no problems, since it's basically just getting variables/classes from a global level.

Comment: @peirix I got it working, it goes like this : `require([myModuleName], function(myModule) { var myModuleInstance = new myModule(); });` where `myModuleName` is the string containing the name of the class I want to instantiate.

Comment: @Mike That's probably because you don't have the global `window` object in node.js. And, that wasn't really part of the question either. I think it should work with the `global` object in node.js instead of `window` https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in node.js with global either. Not sure why.,

Comment: @Mike Probably better to start a new question on it, rather than discussing it here (:

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. After some trial and error I found that this works: `var obj = new Home(id);`, but then this doesn't: `var obj = new window["Home"](id);`. I'm trying to get this to work: `new window[x](id);` where `x = "Home"`... The error I am getting is `Uncaught TypeError: window[x] is not a constructor`

Comment: not working in case of `window[prop.pipeVal]('en-US')`

Comment: Warning: this [won't work for ES6 classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68016983/214517).

Answer (score 58):

Here's a more robust solution that will work with namespaced functions:

```
var stringToFunction = function(str) {
  var arr = str.split(".");

  var fn = (window || this);
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    fn = fn[arr[i]];
  }

  if (typeof fn !== "function") {
    throw new Error("function not found");
  }

  return  fn;
};
```

Example:

```
my = {};
my.namespaced = {};
(my.namespaced.MyClass = function() {
  console.log("constructed");
}).prototype = {
  do: function() {
    console.log("doing");
  }
};

var MyClass = stringToFunction("my.namespaced.MyClass");
var instance = new MyClass();
instance.do();
```

Comment: Why `(windows || this)`, isn't window always going to be defined?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon: The world as we know is no longer the reality. Tenants like nodejs have also come to occupy our planet! :)

Comment: Since strict mode has come along ([*ECMA-262 ed 5*](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262%205th%20edition%20December%202009.pdf) in 2009), `window || this` may return *undefined* in a non-browser environment if *this* isn't set by the call (which it isn't in the example).

Comment: Hi how to use this and make it work for classes that are imported?? e.g. import Grid from '../../mazes/components/Grid'

Answer (score 38):

BTW: window is the reference to the global Object in browser JavaScript. Which is also `this`, and should work even in non-browser environments such as Node.js, Chrome extensions, transpiled code etc.

`var obj = new this[classNameString]();`

The limitation is that the class being called must be in the global context. If you want to apply the same to a scoped class you need to do:

`var obj = (Function('return new ' + classNameString))()`

However, there really is no reason to use a string. JavaScript functions are themselves objects, just like strings which are objects also.

### Edit

Here is a better way to get the global scope that works in strict mode as well as non-browser JS environments:

```
var global;
try {
  global = Function('return this')() || (42, eval)('this');
} catch(e) {
  global = window;
}

// and then
var obj = new global[classNameString]
```

From: [How to get the global object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277182/how-to-get-the-global-object-in-javascript)

Comment: It's only `this` if called from a global context. `window` works regardless of the context you are in, so I see no reason to prefer `this` over `window`.

Comment: Like the answer states, the environment you are in is not necessarily a browser. Therefore, using `this` is preferable, because in a non-browser environment `window` may be undefined, or not what you expect.

Comment: @XedinUnknown Ususally when you write a piece of javascript you know if  it's for clientside or let's say for node. If you know it's for a browser, then there is no disadvantages to prefer `window` over `this`.

Comment: @Sebi, nowhere in the question is it implied that the environment is clientside. Also, clientside doesn't necessarily mean "browser" either.
The answers are providing a way to fulfill the OP's requirements by explicitly referencing the global context - that's the whole point.
I'm pointing out that the only reliable way to reference the global context from the global context is `this`, not `window`.
Furthermore, the most reliable way to reference the global context NOT from the global context is `top`.
Also, maybe good to inject it into the closure.

Comment: @devios1 If you test the code you'll notice it works from any context not just the global context. That's why we do `Function('return this')()` instead of `return this`. The former automatically switches to the global context. This works regardless of context. window can be overwritten, and is browser only. It's good to not know code execution context to write cross platform code. The answer I gave is cross platform and cannot be overwritten and therefore much better than using `window`. It will work in transpiled code, like with webpack, gulp and in node, extensions etc. Please test it first.

Comment: @devios1 I think the confusion here is that the function must be in the global scope. The calling context can be any scope. Which is the same for using `window` without the issues with `window`. The calling context can be any scope.

Comment: If you're using tools like gatsby, it could be server side or browser side.

Answer (score 14):

If MyClass is global, you can access it as a property of window object (assuming your code runs in a browser) using subscript notation.

```
var myObject = new window["MyClass"]();
```

Comment: Does this work in all browsers? I see some posts complaining that it doesn't work for them.

Answer (score 11):

If `classNameString` come from secure source you can use

```
var classNameString = 'MyClass';
var myObject = eval("new " + classNameString + "()");
```

This solution works with namespaces and is independent on platform (browser/server).

Comment: This is identical to the deleted answer from 3 years before.

Comment: I don't know about it and don't know why it was deleted?

Comment: It was deleted because `eval` opens up a security risk for client-side users. Unless you're using javascript in closed production, the best advice is to not use `eval`. It's good practice to not use it in the first place because it may become a bad habit.

Comment: @Jacksonkr, does that also mean I shouldn't drink a beer in the first place because it may become a bad habit? :)

Comment: Per your analogy: Using `eval` when you've heard it's a bad idea is like driving drunk. "Nothing happened ...hic... last time I drove drink ..hic.. in fact I drive better drunk! ...hic..." By the time something goes wrong it's too late. Don't be that guy.

Comment: To advocate NEVER using a function, eval or otherwise, is just bad advice. If it was a function without any use cases, it would've been depreciated and removed as a feature by now.

Comment: Exactly MacroMan. For it to be deleted as an answer is ridiculous.

Comment: Despite this solution is dangerous, it actually works in every environment, specifically in node.js.

Comment: @loretoparisi unfortunately its the only one working for me until I find a safer working solution :(

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using eval. It isn't anything like driving drunk. Just don't let users pass their own input to eval. Do that and you'll be fine. If eval is bad then so is setTimeout which is frequently used and new Function("...") which is in another working answer posted here.

Answer (score 8):

Browser global object is `window` and whenever you define global variables with `var` or functions with `function`, you are adding them in `window`.
Thus you can get your "class" definition there:

```
var args = [];
var className = 'MyClass';
var obj = new window[className](args);
```

**But this won't work for ES6 class declarations**

Classes declared using ES6 keyword `class` are per-standard treated differently.

A class declared with `class MyClass { }` defines a global class that **does not become a property of `window` global object**. In other words the following applies

```
class MyClass {};
typeof window.MyClass === 'undefined';
```

So, how to do the same with ES6 classes? Object access notation is required because is what is needed to parse the string name, but parent object to search in is no longer available.

One way is to create your own context object, declare there your class and search for it there. In code:

```
// this variable actually goes in `window`
var classes = {};
// declare class inside
classes.MyClass = class {
   // the class code
};

var args = [];
var className = 'MyClass';
var obj = new classes[className](args); // dynamic for "new classes.MyClass(args)"
```

Comment: I really like this method, as in my application this is exactly what I need. I do have an issue though, it's kinda on, but also off-topic. How would you implement this when you define your classes in separate files? Beforehand I could import all these classes seperately, but now I'm not quite sure how to 'run' my class file. So that it appends this class to the list of available classes (I hope this makes sense). As my main.js does not see the classes (obviously, because for my main.js the classes are never defined). I'm making a application that runs in chrome btw.

Answer (score 5):

```
function myClass(arg){
}

var str="myClass";
dynamic_class=eval(str);

var instance=new dynamic_class(arg); // OK
```

Edit: inline example

```
function Person(name){
    this.name=name;
}
var person1=new (eval("Person"))("joe");
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is improved version of Yuriy's method that also handles objects.

```
var stringToObject = function(str, type) {
    type = type || "object";  // can pass "function"
    var arr = str.split(".");

    var fn = (window || this);
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        fn = fn[arr[i]];
    }
    if (typeof fn !== type) {
        throw new Error(type +" not found: " + str);
    }

    return  fn;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
import { Class1 } from './profiles/class1.js'
import { Class2 } from './profiles/class2.js'

let profiles = {
  Class1,
  Class2
}

let profileAsString = 'Class1'
new profiles[profileAsString]()
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was preloading data from my server and attempting to load the preloaded data using classes (in particular, I am using vuex-orm). Instead of anything super fancy, I opted for a list of models that I expect, and mapped them to classes that I had already imported at the top of the file. Observe:

```
import Video from '@models/Video'
import Purchase from '@models/Purchase'

let modelClassMap = {
    'Video': Video,
    'Purchase': Purchase,
}

Object.entries(preload.models).forEach(entry => {
    const [modelName, modelData] = entry
    if(modelClassMap[modelName]){
        modelClassMap[modelName].insertOrUpdate({data: modelData})
    }
})
```

Explicit, secure, simple. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

myOption = {.......}

new (eval( varNameClass ))({
param0:'xxx', myThis: this, option: myOption })

Answer (score -1):

On Firefox, there are security rules for extensions, and so for the Javascript console. Don't make the mistake I did to test in the console because none of those solutions work.
Whereas when you test from a page it works better :

- the eval solution works well
- Function('return new '... works (object is created) except for the constructor's arguments that are passed as "undefined"
  I didn't test other solutions.