# Javascript - Cannot get function to set global variable to be used outside function

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I'm attempting to make a simple linear text game that will display inside a div on a webpage. I am using innerHTML to write the contents of the game to the div, and using onclick from a button to change the contents. My problem is that I would also like to include a few user-submitted variables, which I am trying to do using prompt() inside a function.

The problem is, I can't get the variable to set globally. It works when called inside the function, but nowhere else.

I've tried declaring the variable first outside the function, using window.variable (both inside and outside of the function) as well as leaving off the `var` before the variable inside the function to make it global in scope.

I have looked for solutions and nothing seems to work! Am I missing something with the order of my script?

Here is the javascript:

```
var cb2 = '<input id="button" type="button" value="Continue" onclick="replace(\'gamebox\',next3,\'continueBttn\',cb3);">';
var cb3 = '<input id="button" type="button" value="Continue" onclick="getName();">';
var cb4 = '<input id="button" type="button" value="Continue" onclick="replace(\'gamebox\',next5,\'continueBttn\',cb5);">';
var cb5 = '<input id="button" type="button" value="Continue" onclick="replace(\'gamebox\',next6,\'continueBttn\',cb6);">';


var testName = "Test Name";
var player1;

var next2 = "<p>Great, you've certainly got an adventurer's spirit! Now I just need a few details about you and your party.</p>";
var next3 = "<p>First, I'd like to get everyone's name</p>"
var next4 = "<p>Thanks " + testName + "!</p>"
var next5 = "<p>Now you're ready " + player1 + "! Click to set out on the trail!</p>"

var continueButton = function (content) {
    document.getElementById('continueBttn').innerHTML = content;
    };

function replace(id1,content,id2,cb) {
    document.getElementById(id1).innerHTML = content;
    document.getElementById(id2).innerHTML = cb;
}

function getName() {
    player1 = prompt("What is your Name?");
    alert("Your name is " + player1 + ".");
    replace('gamebox',next4,'continueBttn',cb4);
}
```

And here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="oregon.css" />

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="gameContainer">

            <div id="gamebox">

            <p>Welcome to the Oregon Trail! Click Continue to travel the trail!</p>

            </div>

        </div>

    <div id="continueBttn"><input id="button" type="button" value="Continue" onclick="replace('gamebox',next2,'continueBttn',cb2);"></div>

    </body>


    </html>

    <script src="oregon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Define global variable in a JavaScript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)

Comment: have you tried binding the click handler in your script file instead of the markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got your stuff to work.  Take the `var` off of the variables to make them global and change your functions to be assigned to a variable like `continueButton`:

```
replace = function(id1, content, id2, cb) {
    document.getElementById(id1).innerHTML = content;
    document.getElementById(id2).innerHTML = cb;
}

getName = function() {
    player1 = prompt("What is your Name?");
    alert("Your name is " + player1 + ".");
    replace('gamebox', next4, 'continueBttn', cb4);
}
```

This got things working for me.

The other answers here have good points as well, you need a better way of handling the player name.

Answer (score 0):

`player1` is used into the expression `next5`, not `next4` (which is the one of your `getName()` function)

Anyway, it will never work like this. At the moment `next5` is initialized the value of `player1` was defined a certain way, and will remain defined that way unless you redefine the `next5` variable again.

You need to encapsulate the `next5` definition into a function in order to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here

```
var next5 = "<p>Now you're ready " + player1 + "! Click to set out on the trail!</p>"
```

It uses the variable when it is first rendered, it will not be updated when you set `player1` to a new value.

You need to figure out a different way to set the player's name. One way of doing it is to replace it.

```
var next5 = "<p>Now you're ready {player1}! Click to set out on the trail!</p>"
```

and when you use it

```
var newStr = next5.replace("{player1}", player1);
```