# Why variable won't be passed on?

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I have a set of div-s that I need to apply some jQuery to.

```
<div id="anim1" class="animation"></div>
<div id="anim2" class="animation"></div>
```

It looks straight forward, but I wanted to make it a bit more flexible. It might not be possible though...
...but instead of copying and pasting the jQuery function as many times as many layers I have I wondered if there was any way to acquire the layer name from a mouseover action and place it into a variable that I can use in the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.animation').mouseover(function() {
    layer = '#'+this.id;
});

var steps = [0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000, 1050, 1100, 1150, 1200, 1250, 1300, 1350, 1400, 1450, 1500, 1550, 1600, 1650, 1700, 1750, 1800, 1850, 1900, 1950, 2000, 2050, 2100, 2150, 2200, 2250, 2300, 2350, 2400, 2450, 2500, 2550, 2600, 2650, 2700, 2750, 2800, 2850, 2900, 2950,];
  var index = -1;
  setTimeout(function() {
         index++;
         if(index == 57) {
           index = 0;
         }
      $(layer).hover(function(){
        index ++;
      }, function(){
        index -=1;
      });
    $(layer).css('backgroundPosition', '-' + steps[index] + 'px 0px');
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 50);
  }, 25);
});
```

I was wondering what am I doing wrong here. Any thoughts are much appreciated...

update. Tried to declare the variable in the $(document).ready(function(). I am not sure to be honest if I can do this way, but at least the animations are moving now. The only problem is that both stops when I hover over any of them.:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 layer = $('.animation').mouseover(function() {
    '#'+this.id;
});
```

Comment: Well for one, `*` is not a valid character for a variable name.

Comment: @Asad looks like he was trying to Bold the variable name

Comment: Yes, I wanted to bold the variable name to be able to see better

Comment: It doesnt look like you declared the variable `layer`  also, it needs to be declared global. `var layer;`

Comment: @Perren What are you trying to accomplish here? Do you want to move an element to the left?

Comment: @VIDesignz It already is global. Note the lack of the `var` keyword

Comment: @alan_dw Using `this.id` is perfectly acceptable, lighter weight too.

Comment: @Asad Learn something new each day! I had no idea that would make it global.

Comment: thanks guys for thew thoughts. I tried with the 'var' keyword but still not working

Comment: I think the problem is that you are binding the `hover` to an element that hasn't been yet declared on `document ready`

Comment: there is a small animation in each div-s (with moving the background image). I want them to stop on hover. It works ok when I duplicate this script, but would be nicer to be able to use a variable that can pick up the id of the divs on hover...

Comment: That's a goot point VIDesignz, thanks. I tried to amend the code which I will  add to the main post above. The animations are moving now which is a progress, but both of them stop if I hover on 'one' of them...

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I set up a fiddle to show you a solution

Comment: @Asad You should read this, I looked into your global variable statement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function

Comment: @VIDesignz What am I supposed to be looking at here?

Comment: @Asad it seems just leaving off `var` is not a reliable way to declare a global variable within a function, thats all...

Comment: @VIDesignz Yeah, but whether or not it is good practice doesn't change the fact that it *is* global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go man...

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/UBWGt/)

```
$('.animation').each(function() {
    var anim = $(this);

    var steps = [0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000, 1050, 1100, 1150, 1200, 1250, 1300, 1350, 1400, 1450, 1500, 1550, 1600, 1650, 1700, 1750, 1800, 1850, 1900, 1950, 2000, 2050, 2100, 2150, 2200, 2250, 2300, 2350, 2400, 2450, 2500, 2550, 2600, 2650, 2700, 2750, 2800, 2850, 2900, 2950 ];
    var index = -1;

    setTimeout(function() {
        index++;
        if (index == 57) {
            index = 0;
        }
        anim.hover(function() {
            index++;
        }, function() {
            index -= 1;
        });
        anim.css('backgroundPosition', '-' + steps[index] + 'px 0px');
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 50);
    }, 25);

});
```

Comment: Thanks very much VIDesignz. Perfect solution. This is exactly what I was looking for. 
Haven't thought about usung.each(function()

Comment: Your welcome @Perren ... `.each()` is great for times like these!

Comment: @Perren So true... +1 to stackoverflow! haha

Answer (score 0):

You could just set up a variable out side of the scope of the mouse over function and then assign $(this) to that variable inside the function

Var that;

```
$('.animation').mouseover(function() {
    that = $(this);
});
```

Then use that to refer to the element outside the. I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but that's one way to "pass the element on".

Answer (score 0):

When you don't wont to copy your function for each of your divs, I'd use [jQuery each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

I would give each div a class name:

```
<div class="anim" class="animation"></div>
<div class="anim" class="animation"></div>
```

And then assign your effect on each of the elements:

```
$('.anim').each(function(index_each, element) {

  var steps = [0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000, 1050, 1100, 1150, 1200, 1250, 1300, 1350, 1400, 1450, 1500, 1550, 1600, 1650, 1700, 1750, 1800, 1850, 1900, 1950, 2000, 2050, 2100, 2150, 2200, 2250, 2300, 2350, 2400, 2450, 2500, 2550, 2600, 2650, 2700, 2750, 2800, 2850, 2900, 2950,];
  var index = -1;

  setTimeout(function() {
    index++;
    if(index == 57) {
      index = 0;
    }

    $(element).hover(function(){
       index ++;
      }, function(){
            index -=1;
    });

    $(element).css('backgroundPosition', '-' + steps[index] + 'px 0px');
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 50);
  }, 25);
});
```

Comment: Thanks muffls. This is also a great solution. Works well. I should have tried 'jQuery each'... works like a treat too... Thanks again