# How can I create a global var by passing its name as string?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I just read " [Define global variable in a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function) " and I wanted to try to do the same, but this time passing a *string* as the global variable name.

```js
function createGlobal(strname){
    window.strname={
        name:"John",
        age:27
    };
}

createGlobal("myglobal");

//can't use "alert(myglobal.name);", myglobal is not defined and crashes
//however, this works v
alert(strname.name); //John
```

I am really new to objects, I also tried weird things like `window.[strname]`, `window.[""+strname+""]` and `window.["'"+strname+"'"]` without results.

How can I create a global var by passing its name as string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this inside createGlobal:

```
window[strname] = {name:"John", age:27};
```