# Storing values like session in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

On click button event will call a function to generate some random number:

```
  <script>
function connectPoints()
{
 var point_add = RANDOM NUMBER;
 createArray(point_add); 
}

function createPolyline(point_add)
{
 var totalRandomNumbers= oldPoint + point_add;
}
```

Now after client is happy with his generation of random numbers he will hit saveNumbers button

```
<input type=button name="saveNumbers" value="Save" onclick="saveNumbers();" />
function saveNumbers(){
Here I need to get the values of totalRandomNumbers
}
```

I need some mechanism like storing the value of `totalRandomNumbers` in session so that I can retrieve in this new function `saveNumbers()`.

Comment: Does the location change for the user or does he get to stay on the same page? Also see [this](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-storage)

Comment: the user will be on same page, there will not be a page refresh

Comment: define  `var totalRandomNumbers` globally

Comment: possible duplicate of [Define global variable in a JavaScript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 1):

Solutions

**localStorage**

is deleted when user clears the browser cache

```
window.localStorage['randomNumber']=19;
var randomNumber=window.localStorage['randomNumber']*1;
//or using an array
window.localStorage['data']=JSON.stringify({randomNumber:19,total:1});
var randomNumber=JSON.parse(window.localStorage['data'])['randomNumber'];
```

**sessionStorage**

is deleted when user closes the page

it has slightly less compatibility than localStorage

and the example is already posted in your comments.

**global variable**

is deleted when user closes the page or changes the location

```
<script>
var randomNumber;//global variable
window.onload=function(){
 function changeRandomNumber(){
  randomNumber=19;
 }
 changeRandomNumber();
 //rest of you code.
}
</script>
```

as you don't refresh or change location this is the best solution.