# Obtaining Variable from External Javascript File

Tags: javascript, php

If I wanted to extract a variable from an external js file to another external js file.. How would I do that?

For example, if I had a file call example1.js that contained the following code

```
 var test = 1;
```

How would I obtain the value of variable test and put it into my example2.js?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: why did you tag this with php?

Answer (score 1):

You have declare that variable globally. And make sure you have loaded both the files `in order`.

**example1.js**

```
var test = 1;
function myFunction()
{
}
```

**example2.js**

```
alert(test);
```

Assuming you are using this files in php, You have to load the files in order:

```
<script src="example1.js"></script>
<script src="example2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case, not interested in global-variable use like this,

**exapmle1.js**

```
var example1 =
{
    test1 : 1,
    someFunctionName : function(){.....}
}
```

**exapmle2.js**

```
var example2 =
{
    someFunctionName : function(){ alert(example1.test1) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing "var" so make it global to all your js files (no matter if its withing a function), still you will have to **load the js files in order** to avoid problems.

Also you could try add a property to window as shows the answer here:

[Define global variable in a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)

But be carefully of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this question with php ,

I am assuming you need to copy code from example1.js to example2.js , Try this below code

```
file_put_contents("example2.js",file_get_contents("example1.js"));
```