# can't clearInterval on modal window close action

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, modal-window

I'm using modal windows from Foundation and I have an alert every 3 seconds when it's opened.
The point is I want to disable the interval when modal window is closed. I tried the following but clearInterval function doesn't seem to work (alert is still genarated after modal is closed):

```
$(document).on('opened', '[data-reveal]', function () {
            var interval = setInterval(function(){alert("O.K.");}, 3000);
        if($("div#automate_message").height() > 100) { interval; }
});
        $(document).on('close', '[data-reveal]', function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Comment: make the variable `interval` global. Declare it above the `$(document).on('opened'...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the variable `interval` is out of the scope when you are trying to `clearInterval`.

So, First declare the variable `interval` globally.

> Globally declared variables called : [GLOBAL VARIABLES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bzt2dkta%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) - its value is
>   accessible and modifiable throughout the program everywhere.

try this:

```
var interval = null;
$(document).on('opened', '[data-reveal]', function () {
    interval = setInterval(function(){alert("O.K.");}, 3000);
    if($("div#automate_message").height() > 100) { interval; }
});

$(document).on('close', '[data-reveal]', function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Comment: @user3253748: Your Welcome. you could accept answer as a correct answer !! :) Because it can help may other users to find a solution.

Comment: No Problem If you already did this thing. But the "accept answer as a correct answer" means click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer And if you already did this thing then it's a bug on SO :)

Comment: O.K. indeed! :) fixed

Answer (score 1):

Initialise the variable `interval` as **[global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)** i.e. global scope, so that it can be accessed everywhere.

```
//global scope
var interval = null;

$(document).on('opened', '[data-reveal]', function () {

        //local scope

        interval = setInterval(function(){alert("O.K.");}, 3000);
        if($("div#automate_message").height() > 100) { interval; }
});

$(document).on('close', '[data-reveal]', function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
});
```