# Why variable is undefined as I declared globally?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just showing the value of a in alert but I am getting `a` is undefined why?  I will explain the problem:

First I call function with `false` parameter, it show alert with `a = 1;`. But when I pass `true` as parameter, it first show alert `2` (as expected it is local) but when again it show `2`? Third it say a is `undefined`?

```
function ab(p){
    a = 1;
    if(p){
        var a = 2
        alert(a)
    }
    alert(a)
}

ab(false);
alert(a);
```

Unexpected result when `ab(true)`?

Comment: `a` is undefined because it is never declared in the global scope.

Comment: Read this also: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch04_03.htm **and** http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is what called as variable hoisting. and actually the variable that you are thinking as a global one will be hoisted inside of that function and it would turn as a local one.

Compiler would consider your code like this,

```
function ab(p){
  var a;  //will be hoisted here.
  a=1;
  if(p){
     a=2;
     alert(a);
  }
  alert(a);
 }
```

Comment: mean in if condition make a (global variable) to local variable

Comment: No.. Please read about variable hoisting. That would help you in this case.

Comment: where is the concept of varible hosting and function hosting ?

Comment: @PallaviSharma Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 2):

That is not global. you have defined the variable in if condition. its context will remain inside if only. use :

```
function ab(p){
       a=1;
       if(p){
           a=2
           alert(a)
       }
       alert(a)
   }

ab(false);
 alert(a);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fc5qtc41/)**

Comment: I did not get ..whenever I make variable without using var it become global

Comment: You can even skip first declaration `var a=''`

Comment: @PallaviSharma: yes it will. see this answer by T.J. Crowder -http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786899/1719752

Answer (score 1):

You are using `var` inside your function, so JavaScript see your code as below (there is no matter where you use `var`, inside `if` or in loops or ...):

```
function ab(p) {
    var a=1;
    if (p) {
       a=2;
       alert(a);
    }

    alert(a);
}

ab(false);
alert(a);
```