# Strange Behavior of call javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm studying Javascript, and I found this example on my book

```
function sayNameForAll(label) {
    console.log(label + ":" + this.name);
}
var person1 = {
    name: "Nicholas"
};
var person2 = {
    name: "Greg"
};
var name = "Michael";
sayNameForAll.call(this, "global");
sayNameForAll.call(person1, "person1");
sayNameForAll.call(person2, "person2");
```

This outputs:

```
"global:Michael"
"person1:Nicholas"
"person2:Greg"
```

I understand how `call` works, but the output of `sayNameForAll.call(this, "global");` isn't `global:Michael` but `global:result`.

this is code http://jsfiddle.net/rho3zyb4/

Comment: it puts `name` in the global scope.

Comment: The output of that code is the one on the comments you put. Where are you testing it in order to get "global:result" as your first output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function

Comment: sorry I fixed my quesiton

Comment: @Olivia it's still the same.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rho3zyb4/1/ "No wrap" JavaScript gives the result you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running this code in jsfiddle, aren't you: http://jsfiddle.net/4g8q9yor/ - jsfiddle has assigned the iframe `name` which your javascript outputs to as `result` - so you're actually getting the DOM iframe name.

[image]

Create the file on your local machine and you'll see the correct output or try it elsewhere: http://js.do/code/48143 outputs:

```
global:Michael
person1:Nicholas
person2:Greg
```

Answer (score 0):

By default JSFiddle wraps your code in a closure. This means that `var name` makes a local variable, and not a global one.

`this`, in the absence of explicit context, will default to `window` (at least, if strict mode is off it will). Variables will default to global, which become properties of `window` (again, if strict mode is off)

Coincidentally, they result in the same thing, and it works.

But the JSFiddle wrapping messes it up by making a local variable instead, so they no longer reference the same thing - in fact this is exactly why strict mode disables the behaviour - it's not reliable!

http://jsfiddle.net/rho3zyb4/1/ Updated fiddle showing the result with "no wrap" mode.

Answer (score 0):

You get different results if you run this in the console versus in jsfiddle, that is because "this" in jsfiddle is a different object

jsFiddle output:

```
global:result
person1:Nicholas
person2:Greg
```

standard console output

```
"global:Michael"
"person1:Nicholas"
"person2:Greg"
```

Answer (score 0):

By passing this, you're passing "window" and in the case of jsfiddle the window's name is result.

If you run that in another window with a different name, the output will be different.