# Pass Variable to JQM Dialog, from link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I call my Dialog with a link

```
<li><a href='#refPerson' data-transition='pop' id=" + id + ">" + text + "</a></li>;
```

Is there away I can pass a variable which is also the id,  to the refPerson beforeshow function? I am trying to not have to make a phony hidden element. I have tried a bunch of different ways but nothing seems to pass the var.

```
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#refPerson', function(){

    });
```

I have changed how the dialog is called to making the onclick of the link a function that dynamically opens the dialog but I couldnt get that to correctly pass the param either. I just need to get the clicked links ID to the beforeshow function, or somehow pass a variable to it

Comment: Have a look here: https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/passing-parameters-between-pages-multi-page-model/

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using html5 `data-*` attribute.

refer to [this](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

Using `.attr()` to retrieve the value from the attribute. Refer to [api](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you can use [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/), here's an example:

```
<li><a href='#' onclick='getId(this);' data-transition='pop' id='someId'>Some Text</a></li>

<script>
function getId(e){
 var myId = $(e).attr("id");  
 console.log(myId);
 //yourcode...and then redirect...
 $.mobile.navigate( "#refPerson" );
}
</script>
```

You can also assign a [global javascript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786899/797495) and retrieve it on your dialog, like this:

```
function getId(e){
 window.myId= $(e).attr("id");  
 console.log(window.myId);
 //yourcode...and then redirect...
 $.mobile.navigate( "#refPerson" );
}
```

I personally use the [sweet-alert](http://tristanedwards.me/sweetalert) plugin to handle dialogs and messages.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the onclick of the link to a function and passed the param. Then dynamically opened the new dialog. It just seems like the easiest solution to my problem