# Is there a nice way in Scala to convert a List of numbers into a List of ranges?

Tags: scala

I haven't found so far a way to do the opposite operation of List.range:

Existent range function in Scala collections:

```
List.range(1, 4) = [1, 2, 3]
```

Looking for writing kind of toRanges function that could give me the following results:

```
List(1,3,4,5,7,8,9).toRanges() = [(1,1), (3,5), (7,9)]
```

I'm trying to see how's the functional way of achieving it

If you look into [How to transform a list of numbers into a list of ranges of consecutive numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976532/how-to-transform-a-list-of-numbers-into-a-list-of-ranges-of-consecutive-numbers) The answer given is too large and imperative.

Thanks

Comment: is the list ordered ?

Comment: And can it contain duplicates?

Comment: For resolving my current problem the list is ordered and it cannot contain duplicates,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

toRanges funciton may look like:

```
def toRanges(list:List[Int]) = list.foldLeft(List[(Int,Int)]()) {
  case (Nil, i) => (i,i)::Nil
  case ((a,b)::t, i) => if (b+1==i) (a, i)::t else (i,i)::(a,b)::t
}.reverse
```

Comment: Great answer! Though I would recommend `foldRight` instead of `foldLeft` and `reverse`.

Comment: @PaulDraper Possible stack overflow for long lists with `foldRight`

Comment: @VictorMoroz, not true. The standard library implementation of `foldRight` just reverses the list and calls `foldLeft`

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul You are right, somehow I was using 2.9.2 and it did blow stack. `foldRight` you mentioned appeared in 2.10