# How to define global variable in backbone.view.js?

Tags: backbone.js

How can I define global variable to backbone.view.js. Also want to know how to attach this varibale to the function.The purpose for this is to create an object and to pass server side as json format. I tried to define like below code, but it shows error. This is my `view.js` file.

```js
var IrWidgetView = WidgetView.extend({
  //var IreditorObject = IreditorObject || {}; 
    initialize: function (opts) {
        // Inherits parent method.
        WidgetView.prototype.initialize.call(this, opts);
        this.$fileDrop = null;

         this.IreditorObject = IreditorObject || {}; 
         IreditorObject.data = {};
        IreditorObject.data.imgContainer = [];


        this.self = this;
        this.bindEvents(true);
        // Browse server section.
        this.browseButton = null;
        this.browsevButton = null;
        this.browseFileText = null;
        this.$rotatorDeg = $('#rotate-angle-' + this.cid);
        this.$irContainer = $('<div class="ircontainer"></div>').appendTo(this.$el);
        var ireditorObject = ireditorObject || {};
        if (this.model.get('irlink')) {
            this.$irContainer.html(this.model.get('irlink'));
        }

        if (this.model.get('irPath')) {
            var irpath = this.model.get('irPath');
            var irCnt = '<iframe style="border:none;" class="iframe-wrap" src=' + irpath + '></iframe>';
            this.$irContainer.html('<div class="irvidget">' + irCnt + '</div>');
        }
        var rotatedAngle = this.model.get('rotateAngle');
        if (rotatedAngle) {
            this.$el.css({
                '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + rotatedAngle + 'deg)',
                '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + rotatedAngle + 'deg)'
            });
        }





    },
    templates: {
        props: _.template('<label for="name-<%= cid %>">Opacity</label>' +
                '<input type="text" name="opacity" id="opacity-<%= cid %>" value="<%= opacity %>" />' +
                '<div id="file-drop-<%= cid %>"></div>' +
                '<input id="txtServerFileURL-<%= cid %>" class="txtServerFileURL" name="FilePath" type="text" size="60" />' +
                '<label for="name-<%= cid %>">Rotate to</label>' +
                '<input type="text" name="rotateAngle" id="rotate-angle-<%= cid %>" value="<%= rotateAngle %>" />'+
                '<label for="href-<%= cid %>">Hyperlink</label>' +
      '<div id="select-wrapper" style="display:none"  >' +

      '<select id="internalselector" name="href-<%= cid %>">' +
      '<option value="">--</option>'+
      '<% _.each(available_links, function(link) { %>' +
      '<option value="<%= link.href %>" <% if (href == link.href) { %>selected="selected"<% } %>><%= link.title %></option>' +
      '<% }); %>' +
      '</select>' +
      '<%  %>' +
      '</div>' +
                '<input type="button" value="Create IR" class="btn-browse-server" id="btnBrowseServer-<%= cid %>" />' 

                )
    },
    renderProps: function () {
        var available_links = this.model.collection.page.get('available_links');
        return this.templates.props({
            cid: this.cid,
            available_links:available_links,
            loaded: this.model.get('loaded'),
            opacity: this.model.get('opacity'),
            href: this.model.get('href'),
            irlink: this.model.get('irlink'),

            rotateAngle: this.model.get('rotateAngle')
        });
    },

    bindEvents: function (child) {
        if (!child) {
            return;
        }
        WidgetView.prototype.bindEvents.call(this);

        // Fires after image was loaded from users computer.
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:loaded', this.completeFileLoad);

        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:opacity add', this.setOpacity);

        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:irlink', this.setIr);
        // Initialize file drop tool, after DOM was rendered.
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'after:render:specific:props', this.initFileDrop);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'after:render:specific:props', this.initBrowseServer);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'after:render:specific:props', this.initPreview);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:size', this.resizeIr);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'get:iropenPoPup', this.iropenPoPup);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'get:irpopupComplete', this.irpopupComplete); 
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'get:irpopupButtons', this.irpopupButtons);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'get:popupSave', this.popupSave);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'get:createbrowseButton', this.createbrowseButton);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'get:irgenerateGuid', this.irgenerateGuid);

        this.listenTo(this.model, 'get:available_links', this.available_links); 



    },
    setIr: function () {
        var link = this.model.get('irlink');
        if (link.match(/<iframe.*.*<\/iframe>/)) {
            this.ir = $(link);
            var size = this.model.get('size');
            this.$el.css('padding', '3px');
            this.ir.attr('width', (size.width - 6) + 'px').attr('height', (size.height - 6) + 'px');
            this.model.set('loaded', true);
            this.$irContainer.html(this.ir);
            // this.model.set('base64Iframe', '');
            this.model.set('filename', '');
            this.model.set('loaded', false);
        }

    },
    resizeIr: function () {
        var widgetSize = this.model.get('size');
        if (this.ir) {
            this.ir.attr('width', (widgetSize.width - 6) + 'px').attr('height', (widgetSize.height - 6) + 'px');
        }
    },
    initFileDrop: function () {

        if (this.$fileDrop) {
            this.$fileDrop[0].ondragleave = null;
            this.$fileDrop[0].ondragover = null;
            this.$fileDrop[0].ondrop = null;
            this.$fileDrop.remove();
        }

        this.$fileDrop = $('#file-drop-' + this.cid);
        var self = this;

        this.$fileDrop[0].ondragleave = function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();

            if (!self.model.get('loaded')) {
                self.$fileDrop.removeClass('over');
            }
        };

        this.$fileDrop[0].ondragover = function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();

            if (!self.model.get('loaded')) {
                self.$fileDrop.addClass('over');
            }
        };

        this.$fileDrop[0].ondrop = function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();

            // Ignore new file if another one already loaded.
            if (self.model.get('loaded'))
                return;

            // Get dropped files.
            var files = event.dataTransfer.files;

            if (files.length) {
                // Get only first file from all given.
                switch (files[0].type.split('/')[0]) {
                    case 'ir':
                    case 'audio':
                        // Save file into the memory.
                        self.file = files[0];
                        self.model.set('loaded', true);
                        self.model.set('irlink', '');
                        self.$irContainer.html('<div class="irvidget">' + self.file.name + '</div>');
                        self.model.set('filename', self.file.name);
                        break;
                }
            }

            self.$fileDrop.removeClass('over');
        };
        this.$rotatorDeg.on('change', function () {
            var deg = this.val();
            console.log("key ")
            this.model.set('rotateAngle', deg);

        });
    },

   IreditorObject.iropenPoPup :  function(clickHandle, contentHandle, width, height) {
       var self = this;
         width = '326';
         height = '400';
       //width = typeof a !== 'undefined' ? a : 600;
      // height = typeof b !== 'undefined' ? b : 300;
        var fancybox_content = '#fancybox-content';
                    $(fancybox_content).css({
                               'position' : 'relative',
                               'display' : 'inline-block',
                               'overlay' : 'hidden'
                            });
       $.fancybox($(contentHandle).html(), {

         autoDimensions: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 600,
        hideOnContentClick: false,




       //  width: width,
       //  height:height,
       // // autoScale: true,
       //  closeClick    : false,
       //  minWidth: 250,
       //  maxWidth: 450,
       //  transitionIn: 'none',
       //  transitionOut: 'none',
       //  hideOnContentClick: false,
       //  modal: true,
       //  closeBtn : true,
        onStart: function () {
              console.log('onStart');
            //On Start callback if needed

        },
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How to define a global variable in your view is not a Backbone concern , is vanilla JS ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786899/4327861)

```
 var IrWidgetView = WidgetView.extend({
     IreditorObject: {},
     myVar:window["myGlobalVariable"],
     initialize: function() {

         this.setupMyObject();

     },
     setupMyObject: function() {

         this.IreditorObject.data = {};
         this.IreditorObject.data.imgContainer = [];
         //so on

     }
 });
```

or you can add direct into view prototype

```
IrWidgetView.prototype.myVariable = referenceToAGlobalVariable;
```