# In HTML or Javascript, how can I store a variable for everyone?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio

I want a variable that would be the exact same for everyone.
Reason I want this is because I want a download count that people can see.
For every download, the download count goes up.

How would I do like this?

```
var downloadCount = "";
 function addDownloadCount() {
'use strict';
downloadCount = downloadCount + 1;
}
```

Comment: you can not do that, you store this count somewhere in your server then write to it to add one and read from it to get count

Comment: If it is on a server, just use file IO.  (Have a download counts file and just increment.)

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function

Comment: @Liren - no that won't help .  OP wants a count that stays constant across all users requesting data not just to stay constant for one users session

Comment: *in `HTML` and `Javascript`* and you tagged `C#`?!

Comment: Anyways you need to save the count in a database and increase it by every click on your download link.

Comment: @AlexJolig - no , that would be silly to pay for database storage to store a download count number , a text or xml file would work just fine

Comment: @ScottSelby No, it would be *stupid* to do that in the javascript scope. Doing it in the database is an overkill at most. Lets start with a working solution, and only then make it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client side storage locations such as local storage, script variables wont help you in this scenario, since it cannot be accessed from another other users.  You cannot use such a Global  variable for all users in clent side(either html or java script), you have to use server side storage like session or application variable