# Can I insert if statement in else statement in JS?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Can I insert `if` statement in `else` statement ?
The code :

```js
function swicthNum() {
  'use strict';
  var processDoc = document.getElementById('process').innerHTML;
  if (processDoc == 'Dollars to Algerian Dinar') {
    processDoc = 'Algerian Dinar to Dollars';
  } else {
    processDoc = 'Dollars to Algerian Dinar';
  }
  return processDoc;
}
function moneyCalc() {
  'use strict';
  var num = document.getElementById('moneyNum').value,
      lastResultDoc = document.getElementById('lastResult'),
      result = num * 107.39,
      lastResult = document.getElementById('lastResult');
  if (num < 0) {
    lastResult.innerHTML = 'The process don\'t accept negative numbers';
  } else {
    if (processDoc == 'Dollars to Algerian Dinar') {
      lastResult.innerHTML = result;
    } else {
      result = num * 0.0093;
      lastResult.innerHTML = result;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="process">
  Dollars to Algerian Dinar
</p>
<button onclick="swicthNum()">Switch!</button>
<br />
<form action="AdvancedFunction.html" method="post">
  <input id="moneyNum" name="" type="number" value="" />
  <input onclick="moneyCalc()" name="" type="submit" value="Calculate" />
</form>
<div id="lastResult">Result</div>
```

Comment: you mean dynamically? what do you want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki my code doesn't work

Comment: @gurvinder372 no ,my code doesn't work give me just why his don't work!

Comment: Please @SaadLaggoune check your console.

Comment: yeah, No errors clean code @ZakariaAcharki

Comment: Try to add `alert()` inside every statement to know the achieved condition.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki i updated the code ,look if i have some errors by yourself

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can, but in your case you could simply go for:

```
if (num < 0) {
  lastResult.innerHTML = 'The process don\'t accept negative numbers';
} 
else if (processDoc == 'Dollars to Euro') {
    lastResult.innerHTML = result;
} 
else {
    result = num * 0.0093;
    lastResult.innerHTML = result;
}
```

It might be simpler to read.

### Why your code wasn't working

- You set the variable processDoc in a function, so it was not available for the other function: [you have to set it globally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786899/4086503).
- There were spaces at the beginning of the "process"'s innerHTML, so switchNum() never changed its content: [using indexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1789952/4086503), we can check if the desired string is contained in the paragraph, but not necessarily equal to the paragraph's content.
- You didn't change innerHTML of process at the end of the switchNum function.
- On click on 'Calculate', the form was submitted, so it wasn't possible to see the result of the calculation. To prevent that, use `return false;`.

### Working code

```js
function swicthNum() {
  'use strict';
  window.processDoc = document.getElementById('process').innerHTML;
  if (window.processDoc.indexOf('Dollars to Algerian Dinar')>-1) {
    window.processDoc = 'Algerian Dinar to Dollars';
  } else {
    window.processDoc = 'Dollars to Algerian Dinar';
  }
    document.getElementById('process').innerHTML = window.processDoc;
  return window.processDoc;
}
function moneyCalc() {
  'use strict';
  var num = document.getElementById('moneyNum').value,
      lastResultDoc = document.getElementById('lastResult'),
      result = num * 107.39,
      lastResult = document.getElementById('lastResult');
  if (num < 0) {
    lastResult.innerHTML = 'The process don\'t accept negative numbers';
  } else {
    if (window.processDoc == 'Dollars to Algerian Dinar') {
      lastResult.innerHTML = result;
    } else {
      result = num * 0.0093;
      lastResult.innerHTML = result;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="process">Dollars to Algerian Dinar</p>
<button onclick="swicthNum()">Switch!</button>
<br />
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input id="moneyNum" name="" type="number" value="" />
  <input onclick="moneyCalc(); return false;" name="" type="submit" value="Calculate" />
</form>
<div id="lastResult">Result</div>
```

Comment: May ignore the brackets also (just to input more faster): `if(num<0)lastResult.innerHTML=...,alert(1);else if(proccessDoc...==...);else ...`. There's the `switch` also if they're many checkments.

Comment: @ProHands - It is generally bad practice to skip the braces as this can lead to accidental coding mistakes very easily.

Comment: thanks man but no, i wan't to use my method not Else if statement
but my code doesn't work!

Comment: @jfriend00 It depends on what you're doing, but there you have to use commas instead of semicolons, nor for everything works when using DOM.

Comment: @SaadLaggoune could you be more specific? Please have a look at your browser console and post the errors that it points out :)

Comment: @ProHands - We're clearing advising a newbie here.  I wouldn't be going into commas and skipping braces with a Javascript newbie.  The advice should be appropriate for the audience.

Comment: @jfriend00 give me more info please

Comment: @SaadLaggoune could you please update the question with the full code and explain what it should do and what isn't working?

Comment: @Stubborn HTML doc in coming

Comment: @SaadLaggoune sorry for delay, see my updated answer for the working code