# run an ajax call while waiting for the first to complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that will take long to complete (minutes). During the execution a spinner will be displayed (triggered with AjaxStart and AjaxStop).

What I'd like to do is to add a counter of the progress in the ajax call (something like "X records out of 1000 processed so far" with X updating with a second ajax call). The second ajax call will run with a setInterval every 10 seconds. My question is: how to stop setInterval when the first ajax call has completed?
This is the first ajax call:

```
function ajax_submit(){
    var submit_val=$("#stato").serialize();
    dest="plan/new_bp1.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: dest,
        data: submit_val,
        success: function(data){ 
            data1=data.split("|");
            if(data1[0]=="Successo"){ 
                $("#spnmsg").fadeTo(200,0.1,
                    function(){$(this).removeClass().addClass("spn_success").html(data1[1]).fadeTo(900,1)});
                }else if(data1[0]=="Errore"){
                    $("#spnmsg").fadeTo(200,0.1,
                    function(){$(this).removeClass().addClass("spn_error").html(data1[1]).fadeTo(900,1)});  
                }
        },
        complete: function(){
            setTimeout(function(){ $('.container').load('plan/home.php');},2000); 
        }
    });
    setTimeout(function(){counterUpdater();},2000);
}
```

In the end I just call counterUpdater() (waiting a couple of seconds while the counter of all the records to be processed gets updated).

```
function counterUpdater(){
    setInterval(ajax_counter_upload(),10000);   
}

function ajax_counter_upload(){
    //all the stuffs to get the updated count of processed records
}
```

How can I stop counter_updater() from running each ten seconds when ajax_submit has comlpleted? What do I have to put in success or complete function?

EDIT: **I am aware of how to call clearInterval but in this specific case the intervalID will be in the counterUpdater scope only. So how to move it back to ajax_submit?**

Comment: @quentin I have seen that answer but I have not clear how to apply that solution to my code. If I edit my counterUpdater function the variable will be just in that variable scope

Comment: The variable will be in whatever scope you put it in. Don't make it local to `counterUpdater`.

Comment: @Quentin how to do it? I am not so strong yet in JS. :)

Comment: Just declare it in a wider scope.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function

Comment: thanks. I will declare it outside as global.