# JS: Object is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm would like to create an object in javascript which prints the number entred but I get this error.

```
Déclaration d'objet.html:30
```

Code :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  // <!--
    function Init()

        {
            var test= new Object;
            test.affiche= function()
            {
                var champ=Number(document.getElementById("champSaisie").value);
                alert(Number(champ+4));
            };
        }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="Init()">

<p><label for="champSaisie">Saisissez un nombre&nbsp;: </label><input type="text" id="champSaisie"></p>
<p><input type="submit" onclick="test.affiche()" value="Effectuer le calcul"></p>



</body></html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The variable that you are creating, `test` is *local*  to your `Init` function.

When you try to access `test` in your `onclick` handler, it is looking for `test` at the *global* level, which doesn't exist.

I've updated your code to use `addEventListener` instead.

```js
function Init() {
  var test = {};
  test.affiche = function() {
    var champ = Number(document.getElementById("champSaisie").value);
    alert(Number(champ + 4));
  };
  document.getElementById("calc").addEventListener("click", test.affiche);
}

Init();
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="champSaisie">Saisissez un nombre&nbsp;:</label>
  <input type="text" id="champSaisie">
</p>
<p>
  <input id="calc" type="submit" value="Effectuer le calcul">
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you , but no way to keep my code ? because in body I load the function Init  so it should find it no ?

Comment: using inline event handlers `(onclick="blah()")` is considered bad practice by many.  You can't dynamically add or remove them.. you separate your code into two places (the code and the HTML it gets called from).  If you really want to keep the inline handlers then you have to move things to the global scope.

Comment: `Déclaration d'objet.html:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` I get this error now

Comment: I added the `id="calc"` when I made the fiddle. Sorry, I should have pointed that out.  And if your page suddenly reloads after you display the message it is because you are actually submitting the `form` and you sould change your `<input type="submit">` to  `<button type="button">Click me</button>`

Answer (score 2):

`test` is **local** to the function `Init`. You cannot access it in the event handler (`onclick="test.affiche()"`) because it is not global.

In this example there is no reason to put the code inside `Init` at all, you can just directly put

```
var test= new Object;
test.affiche= function()
{
  var champ=Number(document.getElementById("champSaisie").value);
  alert(Number(champ+4));
};
```

into the `<script>`. This would make `test` global. There is no benefit in waiting for the page to load before creating the object.

You could also [create a global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5786851/218196) from inside `Init`.

However, the better solution would probably be to avoid globals and [bind the event](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) [handler inside `Init`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) instead of using inline event handlers.

Related: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500431/218196)