# How to make local varible global javascript

Tags: javascript, global, local

I have this class like so :
https://jsfiddle.net/0sh7fLtp/

When I create a new object of this class, my local variable can't be seen even when I assign to window in the class:

```
function Hilitor() {
    var excat;

    this.setMatchType = function(type) {
        if (type == "exact"){ 
            window.excat = true;
        } 
    };

    this.setRegex = function(input) {
        alert(excat);
    };

    this.apply = function(input) {
        this.setRegex();
    };
}
```

and this is how i call it :

```
var myHilitor = new Hilitor();
myHilitor.apply();
myHilitor.setMatchType("exact");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define global variable in a JavaScript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I completely understand your question but you are trying to compare a variable "excat" to string "excat"... See this fiddle to how you can make your var a string and then get desired output..

https://jsfiddle.net/shemdani/0sh7fLtp/5/

```
var myHilitor = new Hilitor();
myHilitor.setMatchType("excat");
myHilitor.apply();



function Hilitor()
{
  var excat;

  this.setMatchType = function(type)
  {
     if(type == "excat"){window.excat = true;} 

  };

  this.setRegex = function(input)
  {

   alert(window.excat);

  };

  this.apply = function(input)
  {

      this.setRegex();

  };

}
```

Comment: no i want  exact to to be true when create new object of class

Comment: Just edited the answer... Please check it out again.

Comment: This is not the ideal answer. Setting a global `window` var is bad. What happens when you want to initialize another `Hilitor` object? They will both be overwriting the `window.exact` var. See my answer instead

Answer (score 0):

## Two main problems

#### 1) Your `var exact` inside the function is not a global variable and so not accessible on the `window` object. (But that's a good thing).

Your code will work if you remove `window.exact` for just `exact`

```
this.setMatchType = function(type)
  {
     if(type == "exact"){excat = true;} 

  };
```

### 2) You are also calling `apply` before you call `setMatchType`. Switching them like this works:

```
var myHilitor = new Hilitor();
myHilitor.setMatchType("excat");
myHilitor.apply();
```

## [Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/0sh7fLtp/8/)

Comment: sorry but that was small example my original script didn't work as you put  it eather

Comment: yes i did but it didnt work it also give me undefined even if i changed the order