# how to use winwheel.js callback in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, callback

I have been working with a roulette design, where i need a wheel, so i am using winwheel.js library.

```
wheel;


wheelSpinning = false;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.initWheel();
  }

  initWheel() {
    this.wheel = new Winwheel({
      'numSegments': 8,   // Specify number of segments.
      'outerRadius': 212,  // Set radius to so wheel fits the background.
      'innerRadius': 150,  // Set inner radius to make wheel hollow.
      'pointerAngle': 90,
      'pointerGuide':        // Turn pointer guide on.
      {
        'display': true,
        'strokeStyle': 'red',
        'lineWidth': 3
      },
      'segments':       // Define segments including colour and text.
      [
        { 'fillStyle': '#eae56f', 'text': 'Prize 1' },
        { 'fillStyle': '#89f26e', 'text': 'Prize 2' },
        { 'fillStyle': '#7de6ef', 'text': 'Prize 3' },
        { 'fillStyle': '#e7706f', 'text': 'Prize 4' },
        { 'fillStyle': '#eae56f', 'text': 'Prize 5' },
        { 'fillStyle': '#89f26e', 'text': 'Prize 6' },
        { 'fillStyle': '#7de6ef', 'text': 'Prize 7' },
        { 'fillStyle': '#e7706f', 'text': 'Prize 8' }
      ],
      'animation':           // Define spin to stop animation.
      {
        'type': 'spinToStop',
        'duration': 5,
        'spins': 8,
        'callbackFinished': 'alertPrize()'
      }
    });
  }

  public alertPrize() {
    console.log('wheel');
  }

  // -------------------------------------------------------
  // Click handler for spin button.
  // -------------------------------------------------------
  startSpin() {
    // Ensure that spinning can't be clicked again while already running.
    if (this.wheelSpinning === false) {
      this.wheel.startAnimation();
      this.wheelSpinning = true;
    }
  }

  // -------------------------------------------------------
  // Function for reset button.
  // -------------------------------------------------------
  resetWheel() {
    this.wheel.stopAnimation(false);  // Stop the animation, false as param so does not call callback function.
    this.wheel.rotationAngle = 0;     // Re-set the wheel angle to 0 degrees.
    this.wheel.draw();                // Call draw to render changes to the wheel.

    this.wheelSpinning = false;          // Reset to false to power buttons and spin can be clicked again.
  }
```

Everything is working fine, but after the wheel has stopped spinning, it needs a callback function so that we can write our logic after the wheel has stopped spinning, so i am passing it like this,

```
'callbackFinished': 'alertPrize()'
```

but in this case `alertPrize` needs to in global scope so that `winwheel.js` can access this function.
Since my alert function is declared inside component so it is not accessbile to winwheel js.

If i define my function inside `index.html` like this, then it is accessible, since it is in global scope

```
   <script>
    function alertPrize() {
      console.log('wheel');
    }  
  </script>
```

But i want the `alertPrize()` inside the component so that i can write some logic inside it.

Is there a way to tackle this problem.

Comment: hi have you tried to declare your function as a fat arrow function in your component? .. or ... try to use proptotype

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define global variable in a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up modifying the library `Winwheel.js` at line `2266` to remove the eval function that parses the function string to a simple function callback:

`eval(winwheelToDrawDuringAnimation.animation.callbackFinished);`

to

`winwheelToDrawDuringAnimation.animation.callbackFinished();`

Then in your code

`'callbackFinished': 'alertPrize()'` becomes `'callbackFinished': this.alertPrize.bind(this)`

where I bind the component scope to the callback so that it can access component class properties and methods.

Perhaps a better way would have been to fork the git repo and make this change there but I didn't because the repo isn't on `bower` or `npm`.

Comment: U r missing this

`winwheelToDrawDuringAnimation.getIndicatedSegment()`

as the argument for caller