# let keyword - Dictionaries of Dictionaries data model

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6

This query is related to storage structure but not to understand the scope rule for `let` keyword.

---

Using `var` keyword, `a` is a property of `window` object(like a dictionary)

```
var a = 10;
console.log(window.a); // 10
console.log(window['a']) // 10
```

---

`f`is a property of `window` object

```
function f(){}

console.log(window['f']) // function object
```

---

Using `let` keyword, `b` is not a property of `window` dictionary

```
let b = 20;
console.log(window.b); // undefined
```

---

My understanding is, any *name*(function/var/..) introduced in a JavaScript code will be a property(member) of `window` dictionary(nested) object.

**Edit:**

### [image]

---

Whose property is `b`?

Comment: *My understanding is, any name(function/var/..) introduced in a JavaScript code will be a property(member) of window dictionary(nested) object.* And, that is the problem. That statement is not true. See my answer below.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Whose property is `b` in that screen shot? Query edited

Comment: As answered below. `b` belongs to the Global scope. But, because of the use of `let` to declare `b`, it is scoped to a special hidden object that has Global scope. Your expectation that all Globals must become properties of `window` is incorrect and that is the source of your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

None of the code you've supplied relates to a "dictionary".

`var` vs. `let` determines the scope that the variable has. With `var`, the variable is scoped to its containing function (or the Global scope, if outside of all functions).

`let` gives the variable block level scope which can be more granular than function level scope (i.e. branches of an `if`/`else` statement).

If the declaration is in the Global scope, then `let` vs. `var` won't make any difference because the scope is Global.

Both declarations will create global variables, but `let` doesn't explicitly create a named property on the `window` object as will happen with `var`.

See **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)** for details.

Also from **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)**:

> `let` allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the
>   block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike
>   the `var` keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an
>   entire function regardless of block scope.

And, from the **[ECMAScript spec.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations)** itself:

> `let` and `const` declarations define variables that are scoped to the
>   running execution context’s ***LexicalEnvironment***.
>
> A `var` statement declares variables that are scoped to the running
>   execution context’s ***VariableEnvironment***.

This is why globally declared `let` variables are not accessible via `window` like globally declared `var` variables are.

Comment: `window` is a dictionary datastructure

Comment: @overexchange No, it's not. JavaScript has objects and they can be seen as similar to dictionaries, but a globally declared variable just becomes a property of the global object. `window` is an object. `var` or `let` in the global scope doesn't change this.

Comment: It is. `window` is an object, which stores its key-value pairs in dictionary data structure. `'a'` is one key of `window` object, in above code.

Comment: @overexchange I'm not going to argue this with you. JavaScript does not explicitly have dictionaries. It has objects, with keys and values. But, the larger point is that this structure has no bearing on the use of `var` vs. `let`. You are equating a storage structure with scope, which is a false equivalency. Variables declared in the global scope are global and become properties of the global object, regardless of how you declared them.

Comment: As per above code, `f` & `a` are keys of `window` object, which is a dictionary data structure. Scoping rule does not map to storage structure. It is up to V8 engine.

Comment: @overexchange For the sake of argument, let's say we agree. You are still missing my point and the answer to your question. `var` vs. `let` on a globally scoped variable makes no difference. `let` is for declaring "block" scope (more granular at a lower scope), not global. Also, it is not up to V8 on how to map properties or set scope. That is all laid out in the ECMAScript standard.

Comment: Before raising this query, I understand and agree that, `var` vs. `let` on a globally scoped variable makes no difference, which is scope rule aspect unlike my query

Comment: @overexchange Then what, exactly is your question?!

Comment: Copy-paste -> Whose property is b? Did you read this question

Comment: `b` is still a property of `window`. It's just not explicitly attached to it as it is with `var`. This boils down to implicit globals vs. explicit globals.

Comment: @overexchange See my updated answer and provided link for details.

Comment: It does not boil down to explicit global(`var g = 2;`) outside functions or implicit global(`g=2;`), inside any function. First line of your answer is wrong.

Comment: @overexchange No, that's not what I said. Please don't be so argumentative and you just may learn something.

Comment: My question has nothing to do with scope rules. You talk about scope rules using `let` keyword, in your answer.

Comment: @overexchange I have answered your question and supplied a link for further reading/understanding. You can argue all you want or you can read what I've written and possibly learn something. Shouting at the moon won't change it.

Comment: @overexchange Note that the word "scoped" is used in the definitions of each. This is absolutely an issue of scope.

Comment: @overexchange you are coming across as pretty rude. Even if you disagree with Scott or think he is wrong, it would still be good manners to interact nicely with someone that has taken the time to reply to your question

Comment: @DavePile I used phrases like *No, it's not.* or *answer is wrong* unlike the other user using phrases  like *Shouting at the moon*. Can you point any word in my conversation, that looks rude?

Comment: @overexchange: A global environment consists of two parts: 1) A *declarative* environment record, which is basically an internal data structure that is not accessible from user land code. That's where `const`, `let`, `class` and others live. It's the same kind of environment used in functions. 2) An *object* environment record which, as the name implies, stores all bindings as properties of an object. That object is accessible in user land code (it's the global object). You can learn more about this in the spec: https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-global-environment-records

Comment: @overexchange What DavePile is trying to let you know is that from the first exchange with me, you've been argumentative and insisting that your understand of JavaScript is right and that my explanations were wrong. That is not the attitude to take when posting a question seeking help and that is why I responded (after many futile attempts to correct your understanding) that you were, in essence "shouting at the moon" because no matter how much you object, it won't change the facts. Your question makes several false assumptions that you continue to assert as facts.

Comment: @overexchange In fact, this question has everything to do with scope.

Comment: @overexchange Still defiant to the end. What Felix said was exactly what I quoted from the spec. The *"declarative"* environment he speaks of is the *"LexicalEnvironment"* that I quoted from the spec. and the *"object"* environment he speaks of is the *"VariableEnvironment"* I quoted from the spec. Oh, and "You're welcome. Good luck."

Comment: Yes I know that, but his explanation is much better, to get completely clarified