# Send a local variable to out of function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a local variable in my function. I want send my local variable to a global variable.
For example this is my code

```
function moveToTop() {
    var manageTime=setInterval(function () {
        pacmanNowPosition=117//($('.pacman-down').data('top')+6);
        var pacmanOtherPosition=pacmanNowPosition-=18;
        console.log(pacmanOtherPosition)
        $('.pacman-down').css('top',pacmanOtherPosition).attr('data-top',pacmanOtherPosition);

    })
}
```

So guys I want every time send `pacmanOtherPosition` that is local to a global variable that is out of function.

Comment: Why can't you just assign it to the global var? You're already doing that with `pacmanNowPosition`. So why is this one different?

Comment: I know but you must show it to know i'm so sorry but can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are accessible all the time. Just make the assignment while `pacmanOtherPosition` is in scope:

```
// Variables declared outside of functions with the `var` keyword are Global
var MyGlobal = null;

function moveToTop() {
  var manageTime = setInterval(function () {
    pacmanNowPosition=117//($('.pacman-down').data('top')+6);
    var pacmanOtherPosition=pacmanNowPosition-=18;
    console.log(pacmanOtherPosition)
    $('.pacman-down').css('top',pacmanOtherPosition).attr('data-top',pacmanOtherPosition);
    // Assign value to global here
    MyGlobal = pacmanOtherPosition;
  });
}
```

Comment: Man do not work can you connect my pc and help me? thank you

Comment: @سیدامیرحسینرسولی The code I've shown is very simple and will work. If you are having a problem, it's because of some other issue with your code that is unrelated to your question. You should check the Console of your Developer's Tools window (F12) to see if there are errors. We do not connect to individual's PCs and fix issues for them. That's not what Stack Overflow is about.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that will always work is to store it in an attribute of the window.

```
function f(){
   my_variable = 'hello';
   window.my_variable = my_variable;
}
```

Comment: Man do not work can you connect my pc and help me? thank you

Answer (score -1):

This was already asked before in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function).

You could just declare the variable inside of the `moveToTop` function, but without the `var` keyword, which defines it in the global scope instead of the function's inner scope. Something like this:

```
pacmanOtherPosition = pacmanNowPosition -= 18;
```

As you see, no `var` before `pacmanOtherPosition`. Try accessing it outside of the function, and it will work.

Comment: That is widely known to be an anti-pattern. Variables should always be formally declared.

Comment: I don't read it as "How do I make a Global variable?". I read it as "How do I update a Global variable?". Either way, your answer is bad advice.

Comment: Thank but can you connect my pc and help me if you can?