# JS variables from imported module script in HTML are undefined

Tags: javascript, html, module

1. I noticed that when adding `type="module"` to a script tag in HTML with `src="./someJS.js"`, variables from this JS file are not accessible from the browser console and appear as `undefined`. This differs from the same HTML tag without the `module` indication, where all variables can be perfectly viewed from the browser.

I would like to ask for a detailed explanation regarding this behavior.

2. Additionally, I would like to ask if using `type="module"` is mandatory when using an `import` statement within the JS file I am loading into the HTML or if there is any way to get around this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48612021/how-to-declare-global-variable-in-module-script

Comment: *Module-defined variables are scoped to the module unless explicitly attached to the global object. On the other hand, globally-defined variables are available within the module. For example, given the following code:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules