# Javascript: Get the value of a variable inside a function (fetch)

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

How would I get the value of the variable `data` inside `function myFunc()`? Below is a snippet of my code. I want to retrieve a value at this instance `var data = ret;` to use outside the function `console.log(data)`. The code returns an error with `ReferenceError: data is not defined`.

```
myFunc();


   function myFunc() {
    query().then(function(ret) {
        console.log('result', ret); // result "@dara"
        var data = ret;
   });

    console.log(data); // ReferenceError: data is not defined
   }



  function query() {
    var url = 'https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/coyqwdNpWq?indent=2';
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        //console.log('Success:', response[0].name);
        return response[0].name;
      });

  }
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function). (nope, it's async)

Comment: console.log(data);  is synchronous. Fetching the data is asynchronous.

Comment: Just define the `data` variable in scope of `myFunc`. Now the `data` is defined within callback scope.

Comment: just delcare the data variable at the start of myFunc

Answer (score 0):

var data = NULL or [] //add it outside the myfunc function.