# How to prevent setInterval function from executing twice in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, ajax

I am making `JS` `Ajax` call to update the contents of a page every 2 seconds. To do this I am using `setInterval` method. I have noticed that my `setInterval` method executed twice and as a result i get duplicate output. Check the images for reference.

My Flask backend - `routes.py`

```
@app.route('/image/<im>')
@login_required
def image(im):
    image_src=[im+'/'+i for i in  os.listdir(os.path.join(app.static_folder,im))]
    rows=math.ceil(len(image_src)/3)
    print(image_src)
    return render_template('dashboard.html',title='Welcome',images=image_src,rows=rows,image_date=im)
```

My HTML - `dashboard.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div class="image-area">


<div class="container dash-container main-body" >
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <br>
        <hr >
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="jumbotron ">
                <h1 id="hdr">DASHBOARD</h1>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>

{% if images %}

<div class="row" id="info">

    <a href="{{ url_for('dashboard') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="info">
            {% set ns = namespace(counter=0) %}
            <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered images-table" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
                {% for row in range(rows) %}
                <tr class="image-hover">
                    {% for data in range(3) %}
                        {% if ns.counter  < images|length %}
                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="{{ url_for('display',file=images[ns.counter][10:],folder=images[ns.counter][0:10]) }}"><img src="{{ url_for('static',filename=images[ns.counter]) }}" alt="User Image" width="200" height="180"></a>
                                <br>
                                {% set ns.counter = ns.counter + 1 %}
                            </td>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endif %}

</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var first_time = 0;
    var current_count = 0;
    var total_count = 0;

    function update(){
            if (window.first_time == 0){
                window.current_count = $('td').length;
                window.total_count = window.current_count;
                window.first_time = 1;
                //var txt = $("<p class='notify'></p>").text("No new images");
                $('body').append("<p class='notify'>No new images</p>");

            }
            else {

                window.total_count = $('td').length;
                if (window.total_count>window.current_count){
                    $('.notify').text(window.total_count-window.current_count + " images added !");
                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
                    //window.alert(total_count-current_count + ' images added !');
                    window.current_count = window.total_count;

                }
            }

    }
    setInterval(function(){ $('.image-area').load("{{ url_for('image',im=image_date) }}"); update(); }, 2000);
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

`base.HTML` -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    {{ moment.include_jquery() }}
    {{ moment.include_moment() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/base.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/about.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/index.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/dashboard.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/display.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/feedback.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/login.css') }}">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira" rel="stylesheet">
    {% if title %}
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
    <title>Welcome_segregator</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>



    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top  navbar-custom">
    <div class="container" >
    <div class="navbar-header">

            {% if current_user.username %}
            <a class="navbar-brand nav-custom" href="{{ url_for('index') }}" ><span id="header"><span id="logo"><strong>Welcome </strong></span id="header"><strong>{{ current_user.username|striptags }} !</strong></span></a>
            {% else %}
            <a class="navbar-brand nav-custom" href="{{ url_for('index') }}"><span id="header"><span id="logo"><strong>Welcome </strong></span></span></a>
            {% endif %}
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right " >
            <li class="nav-custom"><a class="nav navbar-nav" href="{{ url_for('index') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home "> <span id="header"><strong>Home</strong></span></a></li>
            <li><a class="nav navbar-nav" href="{{ url_for('dashboard') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"> <span id="header"><strong>Dashboard</strong></span></a></li>
            <li><a class="nav navbar-nav" href="{{ url_for('about') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> <span id="header"><strong>About Us</strong></span></a></li>
            <li><a class="nav navbar-nav" href="{{ url_for('feedback') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> <span id="header"><strong>Feedback</strong></span></a></li>
            {% if current_user.is_anonymous %}
            <li><a class="nav navbar-nav" href="{{ url_for('login') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"> <span id="header"><strong>Login</strong></span></a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li><a class="nav navbar-nav" href="{{ url_for('logout') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"> <span id="header"><strong>Logout</strong></span></a></li>
            {% endif %}

    </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>


        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
        <ul>
            {% for message in messages %}
            <li>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}


</body>
</html>
```

The `setInterval` method updates the page every 2 seconds and then calls the `update()` function. update function implements a custom notification at the end of the HTML file which notifies the user if there is any new item. As you can see in Image 1 and 2 , the notifications are being delivered twice on the page.

**IMPORTANT :-** The duplicate values are not being added immediately. For the case when there is no new image, the message "No new images" is added after 2 seconds i.e there is a gap of 2 seconds between the display of duplicate "No new images". However, when there is a new image , then instead of the duplicates arriving 2 seconds later, they get added at the same time. i.e the message "5 images added" and its duplicate version arrive at the screen at the same time.

**Notice the duplicate message updated at the bottom.**

[image: Image 1 .]

**Notice the duplicates at the bottom. Here 5 new images were added to the dashboard and so notification is 5 which is correct but the display is duplicated.**

[image: Image 2 .]

I want the notifications to be displayed only once. 
Please help.

---

**EDIT 1:** - Here is the complete rendered HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script>
moment.locale("en");
function flask_moment_render(elem) {
    $(elem).text(eval('moment("' + $(elem).data('timestamp') + '").' + $(elem).data('format') + ';'));
    $(elem).removeClass('flask-moment').show();
}
function flask_moment_render_all() {
    $('.flask-moment').each(function() {
        flask_moment_render(this);
        if ($(this).data('refresh')) {
            (function(elem, interval) { setInterval(function() { flask_moment_render(elem) }, interval); })(this, $(this).data('refresh'));
        }
    })
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    flask_moment_render_all();
});
</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles/about.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles/dashboard.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles/display.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles/feedback.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles/login.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Welcome</title>

</head>
<body>



    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top  navbar-custom">
    <div class="container" >
    <div class="navbar-header">


            <a class="navbar-brand nav-custom" href="/index" ><span id="header"><span id="logo"><strong>Welcome </strong></span id="header"><strong>dev !</strong></span></a>

    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right " >
            <li class="nav-custom"><a class="nav navbar-nav" href="/index"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home "> <span id="header"><strong>Home</strong></span></a></li>
            <li><a class="nav navbar-nav" href="/dashboard"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"> <span id="header"><strong>Dashboard</strong></span></a></li>
            <li><a class="nav navbar-nav" href="/about"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> <span id="header"><strong>About Us</strong></span></a></li>
            <li><a class="nav navbar-nav" href="/feedback"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> <span id="header"><strong>Feedback</strong></span></a></li>

            <li><a class="nav navbar-nav" href="/logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"> <span id="header"><strong>Logout</strong></span></a></li>


    </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>







<div class="image-area">


<div class="container dash-container main-body" >
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <br>
        <hr >
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="jumbotron ">
                <h1 id="hdr">DASHBOARD</h1>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>






<div class="row" id="info">

    <a href="/dashboard"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="info">

            <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered images-table" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">

                <tr class="image-hover">


                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="/display?folder=07-05-2018&amp;file=%2F07-05-18_02-18-39+PM_0.9997674822807312_0.0002324927772860974_bio_.jpeg"><img src="/static/07-05-2018/07-05-18_02-18-39%20PM_0.9997674822807312_0.0002324927772860974_bio_.jpeg" alt="User Image" width="200" height="180"></a>
                                <br>

                            </td>



                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="/display?folder=07-05-2018&amp;file=%2F07-05-18_02-19-26+PM_0.0011277222074568272_0.9988722205162048_nonbio_.jpeg"><img src="/static/07-05-2018/07-05-18_02-19-26%20PM_0.0011277222074568272_0.9988722205162048_nonbio_.jpeg" alt="User Image" width="200" height="180"></a>
                                <br>

                            </td>



                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="/display?folder=07-05-2018&amp;file=%2F07-05-18_02-19-47+PM_0.9632670283317566_0.03673300892114639_bio_.jpeg"><img src="/static/07-05-2018/07-05-18_02-19-47%20PM_0.9632670283317566_0.03673300892114639_bio_.jpeg" alt="User Image" width="200" height="180"></a>
                                <br>

                            </td>


                </tr>

                <tr class="image-hover">


                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="/display?folder=07-05-2018&amp;file=%2F07-05-18_02-20-31+PM_0.7819413542747498_0.21805864572525024_bio_.jpeg"><img src="/static/07-05-2018/07-05-18_02-20-31%20PM_0.7819413542747498_0.21805864572525024_bio_.jpeg" alt="User Image" width="200" height="180"></a>
                                <br>

                            </td>



                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="/display?folder=07-05-2018&amp;file=%2F07-05-18_02-20-53+PM_0.03425532579421997_0.96574467420578_nonbio_.jpeg"><img src="/static/07-05-2018/07-05-18_02-20-53%20PM_0.03425532579421997_0.96574467420578_nonbio_.jpeg" alt="User Image" width="200" height="180"></a>
                                <br>

                            </td>



                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="/display?folder=07-05-2018&amp;file=%2F07-05-18_02-23-59+PM_6.910012757543882e-07_0.9999992847442627_nonbio_.jpeg"><img src="/static/07-05-2018/07-05-18_02-23-59%20PM_6.910012757543882e-07_0.9999992847442627_nonbio_.jpeg" alt="User Image" width="200" height="180"></a>
                                <br>

                            </td>


                </tr>

                <tr class="image-hover">


                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="/display?folder=07-05-2018&amp;file=%2F07-05-18_02-24-21+PM_0.0027463394217193127_0.9972537159919739_nonbio_.jpeg"><img src="/static/07-05-2018/07-05-18_02-24-21%20PM_0.0027463394217193127_0.9972537159919739_nonbio_.jpeg" alt="User Image" width="200" height="180"></a>
                                <br>

                            </td>



                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="/display?folder=07-05-2018&amp;file=%2F07-05-18_03-27-32+PM_0.8725430369377136_0.1274568885564804_bio_.jpeg"><img src="/static/07-05-2018/07-05-18_03-27-32%20PM_0.8725430369377136_0.1274568885564804_bio_.jpeg" alt="User Image" width="200" height="180"></a>
                                <br>

                            </td>



                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="/display?folder=07-05-2018&amp;file=%2F07-05-18_04-23-40+PM_0.9983899593353271_0.0016100991051644087_bio_.jpeg"><img src="/static/07-05-2018/07-05-18_04-23-40%20PM_0.9983899593353271_0.0016100991051644087_bio_.jpeg" alt="User Image" width="200" height="180"></a>
                                <br>

                            </td>


                </tr>

                <tr class="image-hover">


                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="/display?folder=07-05-2018&amp;file=%2F07-05-18_04-24-43+PM_0.014673426747322083_0.9853265285491943_nonbio_.jpeg"><img src="/static/07-05-2018/07-05-18_04-24-43%20PM_0.014673426747322083_0.9853265285491943_nonbio_.jpeg" alt="User Image" width="200" height="180"></a>
                                <br>

                            </td>



                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="/display?folder=07-05-2018&amp;file=%2F07-05-18_04-25-37+PM_0.028937892988324165_0.9710620641708374_nonbio_.jpeg"><img src="/static/07-05-2018/07-05-18_04-25-37%20PM_0.028937892988324165_0.9710620641708374_nonbio_.jpeg" alt="User Image" width="200" height="180"></a>
                                <br>

                            </td>



                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="/display?folder=07-05-2018&amp;file=%2F07-05-18_04-26-08+PM_0.10836496949195862_0.8916350603103638_nonbio_.jpeg"><img src="/static/07-05-2018/07-05-18_04-26-08%20PM_0.10836496949195862_0.8916350603103638_nonbio_.jpeg" alt="User Image" width="200" height="180"></a>
                                <br>

                            </td>


                </tr>

                <tr class="image-hover">


                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="/display?folder=07-05-2018&amp;file=%2F07-05-18_04-26-56+PM_0.9980469942092896_0.0019529901910573244_bio_.jpeg"><img src="/static/07-05-2018/07-05-18_04-26-56%20PM_0.9980469942092896_0.0019529901910573244_bio_.jpeg" alt="User Image" width="200" height="180"></a>
                                <br>

                            </td>



                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="/display?folder=07-05-2018&amp;file=%2F07-05-18_04-27-32+PM_0.0008696855511516333_0.9991303086280823_nonbio_.jpeg"><img src="/static/07-05-2018/07-05-18_04-27-32%20PM_0.0008696855511516333_0.9991303086280823_nonbio_.jpeg" alt="User Image" width="200" height="180"></a>
                                <br>

                            </td>



                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="/display?folder=07-05-2018&amp;file=%2F07-05-18_04-28-29+PM_0.9541159868240356_0.04588397219777107_bio_.jpeg"><img src="/static/07-05-2018/07-05-18_04-28-29%20PM_0.9541159868240356_0.04588397219777107_bio_.jpeg" alt="User Image" width="200" height="180"></a>
                                <br>

                            </td>


                </tr>

                <tr class="image-hover">


                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="/display?folder=07-05-2018&amp;file=%2F07-05-18_04-29-03+PM_0.0024711675941944122_0.9975288510322571_nonbio_.jpeg"><img src="/static/07-05-2018/07-05-18_04-29-03%20PM_0.0024711675941944122_0.9975288510322571_nonbio_.jpeg" alt="User Image" width="200" height="180"></a>
                                <br>

                            </td>



                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="/display?folder=07-05-2018&amp;file=%2F07-05-18_04-29-25+PM_0.033340130001306534_0.9666599035263062_nonbio_+-+Copy+-+Copy+-+Copy+-+Copy+-+Copy+%282%29+-+Copy+-+Copy+-+Copy+-+Copy+-+Copy.jpeg"><img src="/static/07-05-2018/07-05-18_04-29-25%20PM_0.033340130001306534_0.9666599035263062_nonbio_%20-%20Copy%20-%20Copy%20-%20Copy%20-%20Copy%20-%20Copy%20%282%29%20-%20Copy%20-%20Copy%20-%20Copy%20-%20Copy%20-%20Copy.jpeg" alt="User Image" width="200" height="180"></a>
                                <br>

                            </td>




                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var first_time = 0;
    var current_count = 0;
    var total_count = 0;

    function update(){
            if (window.first_time == 0){
                window.current_count = $('td').length;
                window.total_count = window.current_count;
                window.first_time = 1;
                //var txt = $("<p class='notify'></p>").text("No new images");
                $('body').append("<p class='notify'>No new images</p>");

            }
            else {

                window.total_count = $('td').length;
                if (window.total_count>window.current_count){
                    $('.notify').text(window.total_count-window.current_count + " images added !");
                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
                    //window.alert(total_count-current_count + ' images added !');
                    window.current_count = window.total_count;

                }
            }

    }
    setInterval(function(){ $('.image-area').load("/image/07-05-2018"); update(); }, 2000);
</script>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please share the rendered HTML

Comment: @AswinRamesh Please check EDIT 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I checked your javascript and you are using global window variables that dont exist instead of the local variables you predefined.</strike> Firstly I think you should use the local variables you defined.

```
var first_time = 0;
var current_count = 0;
var total_count = 0;

function update(){
        if (first_time === 0){
            current_count = $('td').length;
            total_count = current_count;
            first_time = 1;
            //var txt = $("<p class='notify'></p>").text("No new images");
            $('body').append("<p class='notify'>No new images</p>");

        }
        else {

            total_count = $('td').length;
            if (total_count>current_count){
                $('.notify').text(total_count-current_count + " images added !");
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
                //alert(total_count-current_count + ' images added !');
                current_count = total_count;

            }
        }

}
```

I hope this helps.

I'll like you to try using a callback function at the end of the image load since its likely the update function might be called twice because the image load might be taking longer than 2 seconds to load its resource thereby causing setInterval to catch up with it.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.image-area').load("{{ url_for('image',im=image_date) }}", function() {
       update();
    }); 
}, 2000);
```

Comment: It did not work. It continued to execute the setInterval code twice resulting in duplicates.

Comment: No it did not work. Same behaviour as before. Also, aren't those variable (first_time , total_count, current_count)  already a part of window object ?

Comment: no they are not, check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window for the window api

Comment: This stackOverflow link states otherwise - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786899/9122915

Comment: i suppose its the update function that gets called twice not the interval since the images are not loaded twice, I'm i right? @BoudhayanDev

Comment: I had the same feeling that the update is getting called twice. So I tried avoiding the parenthesis () after the update function inside the SetInterval . But that ended up not calling the update function at all.

Comment: This is wonderful. It worked.Could you explain how this is different from what I was doing ? Because as I understand it, your code calls the update function after refreshing the page which is what I was doing too.

Comment: Awesome, I figured the image took longer than 2seconds before loading its resource hence the update function was called twice. @BoudhayanDev

Answer (score 2):

Take your set interval function in a variable and simply pass that variable into **clearInterval()** function your interval function execute once only

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 2000);

function myTimer() {

  $('.image-area').load("{{ url_for('image',im=image_date) }}"); 
  update();

}




   setInterval(function(){

     clearInterval(myVar);


}, 2000);
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work. I have added the clearInterval right after the setInterval statement which resulted in complete blocking of the event which is obvious given that I have removed it right after declaring it. The behaviour I wanted was, that the even should execute only once every 2 seconds instead of twice every 2 second.

Comment: No it did not work. Infact this time, there was no alert at all indicating the setInterval function did not get invoked.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 2000);
function myTimer() {
  $('.image-area').load("{{ url_for('image',im=image_date) }}"); 
  update();
}
setInterval(function(){
    clearInterval(myVar);
}, 2000);
```

try this :)

Comment: When the page loads for first time, it works as expected .i.e no duplicates and only one message "No new images". But as new images are added in the backend, it does not display the new status. Which is also expected because you have removed the interval function after it executed for the first time. So, not it doesn't work completely