# How to select elements/values, and "recall" them as a group afterwards?. Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, selection

I am currently trying to code a "product-builder" in HTML/CSS, and was thinking of using Javascript since that is the language i understand the best. (still terrible at it).

Now i was thinking of making it a multiple step process, where you select different "parts" or values, by clicking on a div/img, and after all 5 steps, you will be able to see your selected elements, and make a "order" to the store.

Now my issue is that my javascript is not that strong, and i cant seem to find an example of this type of code. Therefore i was woundering if someone knew a way to select values in javascript, and recall them later. I think this might be easy for anybody that knows javascript, but i cant seem to figure out how to do it.

I found this template, which pretty much sums up what i was thinking. 
https://codyhouse.co/demo/product-builder/index.html

Hope someone can understand my question, and are able to help.
Thanks in advance
Andreas.

Comment: You could use a global variable. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: im currently just cloneing the content in the differnet divs, and pretty much copying it into a new div using onclick. This seems to work, but i dont think it is the best solution for my problem. :)