# Java script - Passing one variable inside addeventlistener function to another addeventllistener function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass a variable from an addEventListener function to another. How could you pass a variable if both of the functions don't have a name? Thank you!

```
     document.getElementById('rect').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
       var index = 5;

     }
      document.getElementById('rte').addEventListener('click', function() {



     }
```

Comment: You would not pass it at all. You would define the variable that is in a scope both functions have access to (e.g. global scope). Every JavaScript function is a closure.

Comment: I can't use global variable, that's the problem. The function I wrote it's just a simple example to explain what I'm trying to achieve @goldie

Comment: why though? ... ?

Comment: @FelixKling so I can't pass it?

Comment: @JonasWilms if I can pass the variable inside the first function outiside the function, well, that work too

Comment: Passing something to a function implies that you are calling the function. But you are not calling the event handlers, the browser is calling them when the event occurs.

Comment: Maybe you want [Define global variable in a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5786851/218196)

Comment: @FelixKling Got it, thank you!

Comment: No, Mr. Bill, No!  No global variables. Wrapping the variable in a global function is the same thing. [jQuery has an event.data property](https://api.jquery.com/event.data/).  The example hints that you could, w/o jQuery,  bind data to some kind of "eventArgs" object that is (perhaps) created on the Event.prototype.