# Check true/false from within function from other function with jQuery

Tags: jquery

i've build myself a jQuery filter option on an existing portfolio page. 
The thing is, theres a onScroll in a function that keeps adding the class 'reveal' on the portfolio items, when they are in the users viewport.

Now i want to disable this function when my function is sort of "running".
Here is my code:

```
  function filterPortfolio() {
    $('[data-filter]').on('click', function() {

    var filterPortfolioIsRunning = true;
    var filter = $(this);
    var filterVal = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    var filterItems = $('[data-filter-item]');

    filter.toggleClass('active');
    filterItems.removeClass('reveal');
    filterItems.closest('.columns').addClass('hidden');

  if ($('[data-filter]').hasClass('active')) {
            $('[data-filter].active').each(function(){
                var filters = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                var object = $('[data-filter-item][data-filter-val*="' + filters + '"]');

                object.closest('.columns').removeClass('hidden');
                object.addClass('reveal');
            });
  } else {
        filterItems.closest('.columns').removeClass('hidden');
        filterItems.addClass('reveal');
  }
});
}
```

Now i have set "filterPortfolioIsRunning" to true, and want to recognise this in an other jQuery function. This code:

```
  function revealProject() {
var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
$('.project').each(function(e) {
  if ($(window).width() > 767 && scrollTop > 0) {
    if (($(this).offset().top + ($(this).height() - 200)) < (scrollTop + $(window).height())) {
      $(this).addClass('reveal');
    }
  } else if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    if (($(this).offset().top) < (scrollTop + $(window).height())) {
      $(this).addClass('reveal');
    }
  }

});
if ($('.project').length > 0) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.projects .columns:nth-child(1) .project, .projects .columns:nth-child(2) .project').addClass('reveal');
  }, 2300);

}
```

}

I have tried doing it like this: `&& !filterPortfolioIsRunning == true` but the console log says it can't find the variable. How can i make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: make the variable global to both functions or pass it into the second function

Comment: Declare `var filterPortfolioIsRunning = true;` outside function at global level.

Comment: You would help yourself a lot if you would indent your code properly ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define global variable in a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a local variable inside the `filterPortfolio` try moving `filterPortfolioIsRunning` to the global space or use the `data` method and store it in an element, like this:

```
function filterPortfolio() {
  $('[data-filter]').on('click', function() {
    var filterPortfolioIsRunning = true;
    // to stuff then save in the element...
    $('[data-filter]').data('filter', filterPortfolioIsRunning);
  });
}
function revealProject() {
  if ( $('[data-filter]').data('filter') ) {
    // no global variables prevent name collision!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `filterPortfolioIsRunning` is declared inside your `filterPortfolio` function. You should declare your variable outside of that (and any other) function.

This way you will have a global variable accessible from other functions.

- Declaring a variable `var n = 1;` inside a function makes it a local variable of that function
- Declaring a variable `n = 1;` inside a function makes it a global variable
- Declaring a variable `n = 1;` OR `var n = 1;` outside of any function makes it a global variable