# How to pass a variable to another event handler in jQuery without delaying it Globally?

Tags: jquery

I have these codes below

```
$('#first').click(function() {
    var TEST = 5;
    console.log(test)
})

$('#second').click(function() {
    console.log(test)
})
```

it looks like this is a weird question but is there any a way to pass a value of `TEST` from above to below then use it.

**Note:** I don't want to use a **global variable** in this case.

Thank in advance

Comment: Declare the variable globally... Means `var test` should be outside the handlers. -- And `test` is **not** the same variable as `TEST`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define global variable in a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)

Comment: actually, i dont want to use global variable in this case so is there any another way ?

Comment: Your implementation (trying to change and re-use the same variable in multiple functions) is built in such a way that you rely on the use of a global, or at least broader-scoped, variable. If you don't want to use a global variable, then you'll need to take a different approach. You should really explain *what you're trying to do* instead of the issues you're having *with your attempted solution*. **See: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)**

Comment: The easiest is to use a global variable. But you also could store the value in a DOM element instead... Or in local storage... You can have it as complicated as you want!

Comment: You could always use a data attribute.  `$(this).data('test', 5);` and then in the other method `$('#first').data('test')` for a getter

Comment: the value of variable 'TEST' is changed depending on columns which user click on. So set a constant value for TEST is not effective

Comment: it is a little bit inconvenience to post all my code here. My example is just a minified case and i thought it was the same. Thank for helping me and have a good nice day all of you

Answer (score 0):

You can create an iife and share the variable in a closure.  Just wrap your code with an iife and move that variable declaration outside both functions

```
(function(){
  var test;
  $('#first').click(function() {
      test = 5;
      console.log(test)
  })

  $('#second').click(function() {
    console.log(test)
  })
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the browser's [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) as well.

```
$('#first').click(function() {    
    localStorage.setItem('TEST', 5);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('TEST'));
})

$('#second').click(function() {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('TEST'));
})
```

Comment: Thank for helping me sir.
The value of variable 'TEST' is changed depending on columns which user click on. So in my opinion, set a constant value for TEST is not effective in this case.

Comment: OP says not a global and you suggest saving it to disk? That's worse than a global variable