# JS Form: How do I push() into an array, without creating a new array every time I click Submit?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Every time I click Submit, its creating a new array with an object

Array should receive keep receiving objects and not create a new one

JS:

```
const form = document.querySelector('#form')


form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const title = document.querySelector('#title').value
    const img = document.querySelector('#img').value
    const story = document.querySelector('#story').value
    const author = document.querySelector('#author').value

    const eachStory = {
        myTitle : title,
        myImg : img,
        myStory : story,
        myAuthor : author
    } 

    let stories = []

    stories.push(eachStory)

    stories.forEach((story) => {
        root.innerHTML += 
  `
    ${eachStory.myTitle}
    ${eachStory.myStory}
    ${eachStory.myImg}
    ${eachStory.myAuthor}
   `
    })
    console.log(stories)
})
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <form id="form">
            <input type="text" id="title" >
            <input type="text" id="img" >
            <input type="text" id="story" >
            <input type="text" id="author" >
            <button>SUBMIT</button>
        </form>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </div>
```

Can someone tell me what  I should do here?

I need to add objects to the same array every time i click submit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define global variable in a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First declare the array outside the `submit` handler. Secondly if you want to append it to the dom you can avoid the array and iterating it. Also iterating over the array may create duplication over row

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#form')
let stories = []

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  const title = document.querySelector('#title').value;
  const img = document.querySelector('#img').value;
  const story = document.querySelector('#story').value;
  const author = document.querySelector('#author').value;
  root.innerHTML +=
    `<div>
    ${title}
    ${img}
    ${story}
    ${author}</div>
   `;
  stories.push({
    myTitle: title,
    myImg: img,
    myStory: story,
    myAuthor: author
  })
})
```

```html
<div>
  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="title">
    <input type="text" id="img">
    <input type="text" id="story">
    <input type="text" id="author">
    <button>SUBMIT</button>
  </form>
  <div id="root"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Everytime the form is submitted, the `submit` event fires up and the handler function is executed. Since, you are initializing a new `stories` array inside your function, every time the form is submitted, a new `stories` array is created. 
You might want to move your `stories` array declaration out of the function, so that new posts are added to the existing the `stories` array.

```
const form = document.querySelector('#form')
let stories= [];
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Submit click it will create new Object and add in array.And next/every click it will add only object in existing array and not will remove the existing Object.

```
const form = document.querySelector("#form");
let stories = [];

form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const title = document.querySelector("#title").value;
  const img = document.querySelector("#img").value;
  const story = document.querySelector("#story").value;
  const author = document.querySelector("#author").value;

  var storyObj = {};
  storyObj["myTitle"] = title;
  storyObj["myImg"] = img;
  storyObj["myStory"] = story;
  storyObj["myAuthor"] = author;
  stories.push(storyObj);

  stories.forEach(story => {
    root.innerHTML += `
    ${story.myTitle}
    ${story.myStory}
    ${story.myImg}
    ${story.myAuthor}
   `;
  });
  console.log("Create data value==>+", JSON.stringify(stories));
});
```