# Trying to pass the var value from the function to the AJAX url

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, var

I am trying to pass the var value from the function to the AJAX URL

```
function gonative_onesignal_info(info) {
    //var pushid = info.installationId;
    //var subscribed = info.oneSignalSubscribed;

    // EXAMPLE
    var subscribed = true;
    var pushid = "123456789";
}

if (subscribed === true) {
    $.ajax({ url: "ajax.php?push=" + pushid + "&key=<? echo $userkey; ?>",
        context: document.body,
        success: function(){
        }});
}
```

only the php value is working for me but so in the console log it display like this: ajax.php?push=" + pushid + " instead of ajax.php?push=123456789

Comment: Why are you calling the $.ajax outside of your function ? Is there any particular reason ?

Comment: Either you can define `pushid` as (Global Variable Declaration)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786899/6656706] or put you `ajax` code into function.

Answer (score 0):

Because the pushid is declared inside a function and is restricted to that scope. If you want to use that value you will have to put the ajax request function inside the gonative_onesignal_info. Look for local scope vs global scope and the use of var and let keywords

Comment: I have tried to put the ajax inside the function but the var value "pushid" is not showing in the ajax url

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php echo $userkey; ?> or <?=$userkey; ?>
```

try again so you can get ..