# undefined my variables in react class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My variables are undefined, none of them, why not? What did I define incorrectly?
Do I need to change the whole method or can I fix some things based on what I wrote?

I put here only the relevant component

Thanks!

Addroom.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Addroom extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        
        super(props)
        this.state = {

            category,
            setCategory,
            roomTypes:[kitchen, bathroom, bedroom],
            yourRoom
        }}

        getSelectedRoomInCategory = () => {
            return roomTypes.filter(
              (yourRoom) => yourRoom.category === category
            );
          };

  
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Select Room Type!</h1> 

                <select onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)}>
                <option value={kitchen}>{kitchen}</option>
                <option value={bathroom}>{bathroom}</option>
                <option value={bedroom}>{bedroom}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: what kind of global variables are undefined? where is the error?

Comment: Those variables (`kitchen`,`bathroom`...) are **not** global variables. [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object, for example, is a global variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function, and you should read about scopes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: You're probably right, I'll deepen and slowly learn, I should have been careful and used that term... thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now its works perfect, all the relevant `variables` are imported and identified.
I used a slightly different method, using the one written below with a little bit of changes.

I made a connection between the written `function` and the call of the function in `return` and correctly defined the `variables` in state so now all the relevant `variables` are imported and identified and everything works. thank you all!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Addroom extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          
            roomTypes:["kitchen", "bathroom", "bedroom"],
            roomSelected: '',
            roomSel:''
    

        }}

    setCategory = (roomSel) => {
        this.setState({roomSelected : roomSel});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

            <h4>Select Room Type</h4>
            <select onChange={(e) => this.setCategory(e.target.value)}>
               {this.state.roomTypes.map((type) => 
                  <option value={type}>{type}</option>
               )}
      
            </select><br/>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like:

- you're missing some imports there (kitchen, bathroom, bedroom);
- unnecessarily overriding the constructor to set initial state;
- incorrectly referencing setCategory (either deconstruct this.state or reference it fully as: this.state.setCategory);
- not setting state.setCategory to any valid values (should this even belong in state or should it be passed down from props? if so, don't copy to state);
- not setting state.category to any valid value (as above)
- possibly missing a value binding on the select;

Comment: You are right, I get parts of what you meant, the answer to my question is also relevant for what you have written, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, there are some errors in your code. Lets try to rewrite component like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Addroom extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        roomTypes:["kitchen", "bathroom", "bedroom"],
        roomSelected: ''
    }}

 setCategory = (roomSel) => {
     this.setState({roomSelected : roomSel});
 };


render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Select Room Type!</h1> 

            <select onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)}>
               this.state.roomTypes.map(type => {
                  <option value={type}>{type}</option>
               })
      
            </select>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

And now you have the room selected in `this.state.roomSelected`.

Comment: I used the method and understood what you did with the `Type` and `roomSelected` for the value entered when the user select in the dropdown.
Thank you!