# How do you call a prompt on page load with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant seem to figure it out. This is what I have so far:

```js
 <head>
  
  <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    var gamerName
    
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        gamerName = prompt("Please enter your name."," ");
    });
      
</script>  
    
    
  </head>
```

Comment: your "var gamerName" is outside of your script tag...

Comment: Please look carefully at the boxes in the live demo editor. You've dumped a pile of HTML into the box marked "javascript"

Comment: @Quentin I thought this was javascript

Comment: It's mostly HTML with a tiny bit of JS embedded into it

Comment: I corrected the snippet.

Comment: ...and then rolled back my edit, because I suspect I masked the actual problem here

Comment: The only problem with that code is that there is HTML in the JS box.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the `var` assignment inside the script tag! Otherwise it will be parsed as HTML.

Minimal example;

```js
let gamerName;
$(document).ready(function(){
    gamerName = prompt("Please enter your name."," ");
    console.log(gamerName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This worked, but we were told to assign the global variable outside of doc ready. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Of course, please take a look at my edit. Otherwise, consider reading about [defining global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-a-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)