# Why is my function scoped variable not getting set as I expect it to be?

Tags: javascript

In this code the I expect it to print `I love Java`. But `var` is function scoped. For this reason it is hoisted to top and saw that it's defined. So I'd expect the answer to be `JavaScript` but wit outputs `Java`, why?

```js
var lang1 = 'Java'
var lang2 = 'JavaScript'

function getLanguage(){
    if(!lang2){
        var lang2 = lang1
    }
    return lang2
}

console.log(`I love ${getLanguage()}`)
```

Comment: You have two `lang2` variables, one in the function and one outside. Remove the `var` from `var lang2 = lang1` and you'll see it do what you expect

Comment: Also don't listen to people who tell you not to put `;` [they're wrong.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/444082/542251)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: I'd also recommend you start using `let` and `const` instead of `var`. [It has much more predictable behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Comment: *"But `var` is function scoped. For this reason it is hoisted to top and saw that it's defined."* exactly. Variables declared with `var` are visible *everywhere* in the function. You described exactly how `var` works but expected a different outcome. What did you expect to happen when a variable declaration is hoisted? Which value did you expect `lang2` to have in the `if` condition?

Comment: Just remove all `var` in your case to get your desirable outcome. Make everything global: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64216485/188331, and suggested to add the trailing `;` in every line.

Comment: Also you are contradicting yourself in your question. First you say you are expecting it to print `Java`, then you say you expect it to print `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 6):

because of Javascript [variable hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp), the code:

```
function getLanguage(){
    if(!lang2){
        var lang2 = lang1
    }
    return lang2
}
```

will be rendered to / re-written (if you will) to:

```
function getLanguage(){
    var lang2;    // undefined local var
    if(!lang2){   // this expression will evaluate to true because !undefined = true
              
        lang2 = lang1   // set the local var to the global lang1
    }
    return lang2        // return the local var
}
```

Comment: Thank You. It's happened because lang2 isn't defined on locally (que. code). so that the condition is true. That's why Java is printed.