# How to make global variable inside a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

So I coded this function expecting to create a variable, but it throw me an error

```
function createMyName(){
  var Myname = 'something';
  console.log(Myname); //something
}
console.log(Myname) //⚠ Myname is not defined
```

Comment: This is really a poor question.  As many, I'm sure, will point out you can use window for your global variables, but I'd have to ask why you'd ever want to do that.  It's a very good example of an [anti-pattern](https://medium.com/swlh/javascript-antipatterns-globals-and-variables-ec6229793b37).  An more likely that question has already been asked on SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define a global variable in a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-a-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the variable outside the function than change it inside the function
when defining the function use global like the following

```
global.myGlobalVariable = "Value 1";

function myFunction(){
   myGlobalVariable = "Value 2";
}
```

it would be changed as a global variable