# How do I make custom JavaScript console commands?

Tags: javascript, console

I've been trying to make custom console commands with JavaScript with no success. There seem to be no sources about my question.

When I say "JavaScript Console Commands" I mean I'd like to make my own commands from the console. For example, if the visitor types "`custom.command()`" in my website's console area, I want the output to be: `console.log("This is my custom command");`.

Comment: Write a function.

Comment: @tkausl, Thank's for reaching out! Can you be a little more spesific? What is the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special; just create an object at global scope with functions on it, and the user will be able to use it from the devtools console.

For instance (in a script, not a module):

```
const custom = {
    command() {
        console.log("This is my custom command.");
    },
};
```

Using it:

```
custom.command();
```

Because that's at global scope, it creates a global, and so it is accessible in the console when your page is open.

(It doesn't have to be an object; you could just create a function at global scope, but your example usage was using an object.)

---

If you wanted to do this from a module, since the top level of a module isn't global scope, you'd have to do the same kind of thing you have to do to create a global in a function, which is covered by the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-a-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function). In your case, it's: assign to a property on `window`: `window.custom = { /*...*/ };` Or in modern browsers, use can use `globalThis` (which refers to the same object): `globalThis.custom = { /*...*/ };` (unlike `window`, `globalThis` is available in non-browser environments).