# How to use a variable within a function and use it in a secondary function? Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

How to get a local variabel to be set into a global one and use it in a secondary function? function 1 will be called in HTML initially then function 2 will be called...

```js
function test1(){
  var test1 = 1;
}

function test2(){
  var test2 = test1 + 3;
}
```

Comment: You don't. Declare the variable as global in the first place.

Comment: Can you show us where/when (and in what order) you are calling `test1()` and `test2()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define a global variable in a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-a-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)

Comment: "*function 1 will be called in HTML initially then function 2 will be called...*" - still not quite clear. How often are they going to be called? Why not just use a single function, where a local variable works? Why not declare the variable as global in the first place if a global variable is really what you want?