# How to NOT generate a script "module" with ViteJS?

Tags: javascript, vite

I use ViteJS to generate a library, and the index.html.

I want to generate the simplest script possible in dist/index.html : `<script src="...">`, without `type=module`

In the root `index.html` I have to set the script as a `type=module`, if not ViteJS will not handle it.

So is there any way to configure ViteJS to control how the "<script>" is generated ?

The root index.html :

```
...
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
    ...
  </body>
...
```

The actual result dist/index.html (type=module and crossorigin) :

```
...
  <head>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-3ba57d45.js"></script>
    ...
  </head>
...
```

Wanted result in dist/index.html :

```
...
  <head>
    <script src="/assets/index-3ba57d45.js"></script>
    ...
  </head>
...
```

Thanks !