# Do global variables carry their values assigned in one function in all other functions too

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I am a new in programming.
I have a question about global variables. I am a little confused on how the variable I declared globally and assigned it a value in my first button handler function works in other functions too.

```
let currentAccount;

btnLogin.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  currentAccount = accounts.find(
    acc => acc.username === inputLoginUsername.value
  );
  if (currentAccount?.pin === Number(inputLoginPin.value)) {
    //Display UI AND Message
    labelWelcome.textContent = `Welcome back ${
      currentAccount.owner.split(' ')[0]
    }`;
    containerApp.style.opacity = 100;
    //Clear inputfields
    inputLoginUsername.value = inputLoginPin.value = '';
    inputLoginPin.blur();
    //Display Movements
    displayUI(currentAccount);
  }
});

btnTransfer.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const amount = Number(inputTransferAmount.value);
  const receiverAcc = accounts.find(
    acc => acc.username === inputTransferTo.value
  );
  inputTransferAmount.value = inputTransferTo.value = '';
  if (
    amount > 0 &&
    receiverAcc &&
    currentAccount.balance >= amount &&
    receiverAcc?.username !== currentAccount.username
  ) {
    currentAccount.movements.push(-amount);
    receiverAcc.movements.push(amount);

    displayUI(currentAccount);
  }
  console.log(currentAccount);
});
```

I thought I had to reassign currentAccount variable because was declared in another function and we don`t have access to the variables or in this case the values of other functions variables.

Comment: "I thought I had to reassign currentAccount variable because was declared in another function" - but it *wasn't* declared in another function.

Comment: Fairly old answer so doesn't include `let` and `const` - but might give you an insight: [define a global variabine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-a-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much the point of a *global* variable ...