# AJAX - retrieve multiple data

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I use some data as `global`? For example:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "php/setting.php",
      data: { name: name, lastname: lastname, firstname: firstname
      }
      dataType: 'html',
      context: document.body,
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        //how to get this name,lastname, and firstname
      }
});
```

How can I get this *name, lastname, firstname*, and use it as a `global variable` like:

```
 if(name == 'archie') {
 }
```

thanks.

Comment: Do not perform synchronous ***Asynchronous Javascript And XML (AJAX)***, remove the async : false, and read -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Put the ajax call inside a function and declare those variables inside that function as well.  That way they'll be accessible in the success callback.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352020/jquery-the-best-way-to-set-a-global-variable

Comment: thank you sir for answering my question. got some ideas in those links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var name="the name";
var lastname="the lastname";
var firstname="the firstname";

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "php/setting.php",
  data: { name: name, lastname: lastname, firstname: firstname},
  dataType: 'html',
  context: document.body,
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    if(name == 'archie') {
         //you can use it
    }
  }
  });
```

Comment: thank you sir for answer my question, the thing is i want the name to be global, so i can call it any time.

Comment: @reyes Prefix the variable names with `window.`, and do some reading about variable scope in Javascript - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Comment: @reyes if you define the variable at very beginning of script, then you can use it anywhere. for example if you define `var name;` just below `$(document).ready(function() {`, then you can use `name` anywhere inside the `document.ready` function

Comment: @suhail how can i get the name in the ajax and call it any time.
is this possible success: function(data) {var name=data.name}?

Comment: @reyes `data` is the value return from `php/setting.php` script. i am not good at php. may be you may need to return array {'name':"sdffds"...} in `setting.php`. then you can use `data.name`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understand the question but I think what you want to do is to set up an empty variable in your namespace (or in the global namespace if that's how you're doing it) such as `var name;` and then when you perform your AJAX request you want to do something like

```
success: function(data) {
    name = data.name
  }
```