# Javascript, create a global variable with window[]

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

So, i'm in an ajax request, in the success callback :

```
var just_id = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/tw/www/search/",
                data: {search:tw_search,  type:'tw_search'},
                success: function (html) {
                            window[just_id] = $(this).attr('tw_username');
                }
            });
```

With this code, after i call with ajax my script, i need to create a variable with the name of a specific element.

So, if i'm on a `<div id="test"></div>`, in `var just_id` i have `test` and then, i create a variable `test` with `window[just_id]`.

But i need to retrieve this variable in an other function on my page.. How can i do that ? I need to create a global variable with windows[]... Thanks !

Comment: You can retrieve it in the same way. `window['test']`. Or do you need the 'test' bit in a global variable?

Comment: Just declare variable globally and use it..why are you messing up with window object?

Comment: Unless you're creating a global name space, you **don't** "_need to create a global variable_".  There is always a better solution.

Comment: I have the variable just_id in my first function, i can't retrieve this id in other...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352020/jquery-the-best-way-to-set-a-global-variable

Comment: @Pilot using `window.foo = 'bar'` is actually safer (and also permitted in strict mode) than just saying `foo = 'bar'` without a `var` qualifier.  It makes it clear that the explicit intent is to declare a global (however bad an idea that may be).

Comment: Why are you performing an ajax call if you aren't using any of the fetched data in the `success` fuction?

Answer (score 0):

Can't directly assign indexed value to window object. But you can do in this way:

```
window.x = new Array();
window.x[4] = 'value here';

// And can read from any function like here
;(function(){
 alert(window.x[4]);
})();
```

For your script above:

```
window.global = new Array();
window.global[just_id] = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/tw/www/search/",
    data: {search:tw_search,  type:'tw_search'},
    success: function (html) {
       window.global[just_id] = $(this).attr('tw_username');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `window` to declare global variable:

```
window.globalVar[];// i have not give window as varible name this may cause error it must be reserved
var just_id = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/tw/www/search/",
    data: {search:tw_search,  type:'tw_search'},
    success: function (html) {
        globalVar[just_id] = $(this).attr('tw_username');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

NB! First of all, if you are using this in success callback in ajax, this would have different context, not what you are expecting.

Answer: you can define some variable in top of function declaration

```
var just_id = $(this).attr('id'),
    attrUsername;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/tw/www/search/",
    data: {
        search: tw_search,
        type: 'tw_search'
    },
    success: function (html) {
        attrUsername = $(this).attr('tw_username');
    }
});
```

Then, you can access to this variable. Avoid to use global variable for your purpose