# jQuery global variable couldn't load

Tags: jquery, global

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    var totalTitles = "";

    function getSubtitles() {
        for(var i=0; i<currentArray.length; i+=2) {
            totalTitles += "<li><a href='" + currentArray[i+1] + "'>" + currentArray[i] + "</a></li>";
        }

        alert(totalTitles);
    }

    $("#menu-header .mainTitles").click(function() {
        getSubtitles();
    });

    alert(totalTitles);
});
```

I can load the `totalTitles` variable in a `for` loop. However, when the `for` loop is finished, the `totalTitles` variable has the default value of `" "`.

Comment: please take look at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352020/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-global-variable-in-javascript

Comment: What is the length of `currentArray`? It's probably 0...

Comment: currentArray isn't important. This is part of my code. I mean you can delete currentArray. My problem how do i set the global veriable in function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
    window.totalTitles = "";

    $(document).ready(function() {  

        function getSubtitles() {
            for(var i=0; i<currentArray.length; i+=2) {
                window.totalTitles += "<li><a href='" + currentArray[i+1] + "'>" + currentArray[i] + "</a></li>";
            }

            alert(window.totalTitles);
        }

        $("#menu-header .mainTitles").click(function() {
            getSubtitles();
        });

        alert(window.totalTitles);
    });
```

Comment: $("#menu-header .mainTitles").click(function() {
    getSubtitles();
}); If i use it like this totalTitles happens default when the click function over. But i use the funciton without $("#menu-header .mainTitles").click() totalTitles doesnt happen default value.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    var x = "";

    $("#anyElement").click(function() {
        x = "test";
        alert(x);
    });

    alert(x);
});
```

When firs alert works, messagebox shows "test".
 when second alert works, messagebox shows " ".

```
    $("#anyElement").click(function() {
        // How can i set the x veriable as "test" here
    });
```

Comment: is it another question ? // How can i set the x veriable as "test" here

Comment: well if you don't click the 'anyElement' , the second alert shows nothing ! but loot at this link,hope you can solve your problem http://jsfiddle.net/ay7vdhk9/

Comment: and for updating a question you should edit the main question please. http://stackoverflow.com/tour