# Proper display of user editing form (CRUD model) with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, checkbox

I'm making a simple CRUD model with input checkbox. I have no problems on server side, everything is fine. I use NodeJS +MongoDB. But I have problem in editing existing user. When I edit an existing user with a checked checkbox( I get JSON object with parameter `checked=true` ) how should I display it using JS? 
This is part of my **users.js** file in **/routes/** folder

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../../models/User');
var rest = require('restler');
router.get('/adduser', function(req, res){
  var user = new User();
  user.contacts.push({phone: '', email: ''});
  rest.get('http://localhost:3000/api/adduser').on('complete', function(data) {
    res.render('users/add', { title: 'Add New Users' , n: user});
  });
});
```

And this is **views/users/fields.jade** part of file for better understanding:

```
.form-group
label.col-sm-2.control-label(for='email') E-mail:
.col-sm-10
input(type="email", placeholder="email", name="email", value = n.contacts[0].email,required)
.form-group
.col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-10
input#enabled(type="checkbox",style='text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;',placeholder="", name="enabled", value = n.enabled)
| Enable user
```

So my problem is that I don't understand how I should display that checkbox is really checked when loading existing user. 
If user is checked attribute `n.enabled=true` and if not `n.enabled=false`. So if user is checked on load of that user I need the input filed to be checked.
I've tried it to do the following way, but it wrote me that n wasn't defined...and I don't know how to pass n as the  parameter for that function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(n.enabled=="true"){$("enabled").toggle(this.checked);}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `fields.jade`, change `value = n.enabled` to `checked = (n.enabled ? 'checked' : '')`

Comment: it is still the same, I need to pass n to this function. But actually I can't get how to do this.

Comment: Ah ok, maybe in `fields.jade` instead of `value = n.enabled` try `checked = (n.enabled ? 'checked' : '')`

Comment: that woked for me, just posted an answer and then read your comment, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `#` for `id-selectors` and use `n.enabled` directly to hide or show your element like,

```
 $("#enabled").toggle(n.enabled);
 //-^ prepend # before id selectors
```

[toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) will show/hide your element, To check uncheck use the [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#enabled").prop("checked",n.enabled);
});
```

Comment: Ok, but I still have a problem with passing n to this function. When I run my code it says that n is not defined

Comment: Obviously, you will get this error, if you will not initialize `n` as an object having `enabled` as a `property` in it. When you are using that property, at that time it must be defined.

Comment: But it's already defined in users.js, isn't it? Because here "input(type="email", placeholder="email", name="email", value = n.contacts[0].email,required)" it works correctly or I just don't understand smth?

Comment: If it is, then make it global so that you can access it everywhere in all other js files. You can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352020/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-global-variable-in-javascript