# Create a global variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have a problem with a JavaScript variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var numbers = [1,2,2,2]
    })
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        console.log(numbers) 
    })
</script>
```

Console doesn't show anything. How can I use numbers in the second script?

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "best" way to set a global variable in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352020/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-global-variable-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a variable between two script tags, you have to define it in the global scope.  Also, you don't have anything named `array`?  The following would work:

```
<script>
    var numbers = null;
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        numbers = [1,2,2,2];
    });
</script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        console.log(numbers);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: not sure where you're getting `array` from, I don't see that in the question?

Comment: There was an edit to the original post.  Originally it was `console.log(array)`

Answer (score 0):

No, you have defined `numbers` inside the scope of the first `ready` function, thus is not defined inside the second function. You would have to declare the variable outside of the function to give it the scope you need here. However, unless you have a reason to use 2 separate scripts here, I don't suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it. I use "window.numbers = [1,2,2]" and then in the second script I call it "window.numbers". But i don't know when i use this way, it will good or not for performance.