# How to global a js var in a function?

Tags: javascript, html

It is possible to global a variable inside a function, if not, how can I access a var in function b from function a.

```
var money;
var moneyInput = document.getElementById('input');

function check(){
if (moneyInput.value == "") {
    money = 100;
}                   

function hit() {
    document.write(money) // will this money var be 100 or undefined?
}
```

Comment: post the example code

Comment: *"It is possible to global a variable inside a function"* Yes. *"how can I access a var in function b from function a"* You usually pass the value as argument to the function. Having to use global variables could be an indicator of bad design. Can you provide more information/context about what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: Also please use the search because this is a possible duplicate of [How to declare a global variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3352020/218196)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare a global variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352020/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Just declare that variable outside function and then use it inside of that function.

P.S Please, post some code that you tried already.

```js
let a = 5;
let b = 0; // Declare global variable

function printAB(_b) {
  b = _b; // Set new value through this function
  console.log(a, b);
}

function printBC() {
  let c = 7;
  console.log(b, c); // Get b variable
}

printBC(); // 0, 7 // b = 0
printAB(2); // 5, 2
printBC(); // 2, 7 // b = 2
```

### Edit

With code you provided, answer is simple. Variable `money` can be equal `100` or be `undefined`, that depends if function `hit` will be called before function `check`.

Comment: So did I. Check it and mark as answered if that's what you wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign a value to an undeclared variable in a function it will be created as a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the variable outside of the function scope:

```
var myGlobalVar = "foo";

function a(){
   var myLocalVar = 'bar';
   alert(myGlobalVar); //shows foo
   alert(myLocalVar); //shows bar
}

function b(){
   var myLocalVar = 'baz';
   alert(myGlobalVar); //shows foo too
   alert(myLocalVar); //shows baz
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign a variable without using `var`, `let`, or `const`

```
var foo = 'bar';

function fn() {
  console.log(foo);
  bar = 'xyz';
}

fn()

console.log(bar)
```

Repl: https://repl.it/languages/javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a value to the global object ( window in browsers):

```js
function a(){
  window.test="test";
}
function b(){
 console.log(test);
}
a(),b();
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaring the variable on the outer scope and using it inside should solve your problem. However if you insist on creating a variable on the global scope you can do the following;

```
window.VAR_NAME = 'foo';
```

By doing so you are actually creating a global variable `VAR_NAME` and it now has the value foo.

Answer (score 1):

/* 1 */

```
var a = 'sample text';

function one() {
  a = 'modified text';
}

function two() {
  console.log(a);
}

one();
two();
```

/* 2 */

```
function one(callback) {
  var a = 'sample text callback';
  callback(a);
}

function two() {
  one(function(a) {
    console.log(a);
  });
}

two();
```

/* 3 */

```
var one = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var a = 'sample text promise';
  resolve(a);
});

function two() {
  one.then(function(a) {
    console.log(a);
  });
}

two();
```

/* 4 */

```
var myGlobals = {};

function one() {
  myGlobals.a = 'sample text';
}

function two() {
  console.log(myGlobals.a);
}

one();
two();
```