# Moving a local scoped variable to global scope so I can import it to another JS file

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, global-variables, local-variables

Im trying to convert an excel sheet into a json object in javascript and Im having problems retrieving the final data as it is scoped locally. I would like to take the variable labelled as "inputData" and export it to another JS file however in order to do that it has to be at the top level of a file, which I assume means it has to be global scope. I cant for the life of me figure out how to get it from its local scope though. Any help would be appreciated.

Take a look at the code:

```
let selectedFile;

document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
})
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {

    if (selectedFile) {
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile);
        fileReader.onload = (event) => {
            let data = event.target.result;
            let workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: "binary" })
            let rowObject = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets.Grid);
            let newData = rowObject.filter((item, index) => {
                return index === rowObject.findIndex((obj) => {
                    return JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(obj)
                })
            })

            newData.pop()

            let inputData = JSON.stringify(newData, undefined, 4)
            console.log(inputData)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: For browser-based app: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3352033/2055998

Comment: Just do the same with `inputData` as you did with `selectedFile` - declare the `let` globally not inside the function???

Comment: Where, how, and **when** are you trying to access `inputData`? Notice that `onload` is asynchronous, so the variable will not be assigned immediately when the button is clicked. Really you probably should *call* a function provided by the other file with the JSON result as soon as you produced it.

Comment: How are you embedding those JS files in your html page? Are you using ES modules?

Comment: I tried doing the same with the inputData as the selectedFile variable but it wouldnt export and would get the error that says the variable has to be at the top level

Comment: And yes I am embedding the JS with ES Modules

Comment: By "*doing the same as with `selectedFile`*", I meant declaring it at the top level (and not inside either event handler where it is used). If you place `let inputData;` right next to `let selectedFile;` it should work, and you should be able to `export` them both. Although, as I said, this is probably useless since the other module still wouldn't known *when* the variable would be set to its value.

Comment: So again, please post the code of the other module where you want to use `inputData`.

Answer (score -1):

You can export a mutable object as reference instead:

```
let selectedFile;

export const MyExport = { inputData: undefined };

document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
})
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {

    if (selectedFile) {
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile);
        fileReader.onload = (event) => {
            let data = event.target.result;
            let workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: "binary" })
            let rowObject = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets.Grid);
            let newData = rowObject.filter((item, index) => {
                return index === rowObject.findIndex((obj) => {
                    return JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(obj)
                })
            })

            newData.pop()

            MyExport.inputData = JSON.stringify(newData, undefined, 4)
            console.log(inputData)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Would this allow me to use the data that I have in the inputData variable inside of another JS file? The main thing I need is that data which is local scoped inside the onload event handler

Comment: OP is asking about `inputData` not about `selectedFile`

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can of course name the `MyExport` however you like.