# javascript array with names of variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I have an array with the name of some of my variables. Don't ask why.
I need to foreach() that array and use the values of it as variables names.
My variables exists and contain data.

Example:

```
myArray = ["variable.name", "variable.age", "variable.genre"];
variable.name = "Mike";
console.log(treat_it_as_variable_name(myArray[0]));
```

Console should now display: Mike

Is it even possible in javascript?

Comment: Will the strings in the array always refer to the same `variable.`? (i.e. only the last part, the property, differs)

Comment: you wont to rename variables?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Javascript let's you access object properties dynamically. For example,

```
var person = {name:"Tahir Akhtar", occupation: "Software Development" };
var p1="name";
var p2="occupation";
console.log(person[p1]); //will print Tahir Akhtar
console.log(person[p2]); //will print Software Development
```

`eval` on the other hand lets you evaluate a complete expression stored in a string variable.

For example (continuing from previous example):

```
var tahir=person;
console.log(eval('person.occupation'));//will print Software Development
console.log(eval('tahir.occupation'));//will print Software Development
```

In browser environment top level variables get defined on `window` object so if you want to access top level variables you can do `window[myvar]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `eval(myArray[i])` to do this.  Note that `eval()` is considered bad practice.

You might consider doing something like this instead:

```
var myArray = ["name", "age", "genre"];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(variable[myArray[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the variable yourself:

```
var t = myArray[0].split(".");
console.log(this[t[0]][t[1]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277182/how-to-get-the-global-object-in-javascript) for how to get hold of the gloabal object and then index into that:

```
var global = // code from earlier question here
console.log(global[myArray[0]])
```

Hmm... I see now that your "variable names" contain dots, so they are not actually single names. You'll need to parse them into dot-delimited parts and do the indexing one link at a time.