# javascript "use strict" and Nick's find global function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

So I saw a function that was, quite frankly beautiful in its simplicity as it allowed you to find the global object ( which depending on environ at the time may NOT have been window ) while within an anonymous function; however when you throw javascripts' "use strict"; mode it crumbles, due to the evaluation of the keyword 'this' changing. There were a few ways to accomplish this?

```
(function () {
    var win = function () {
        return (function () {
                return this;
            }());
        };
    //win now points to the global object no matter where it is called.
}());
```

Now, if these are called within the context of "use strict" we lose the functionality described, is there any equivalent that can be done in ES5 strict mode?

For reference

```
(function () {
    "use strict"
    //code here is in strict mode
}())
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the Global Object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277182/how-to-get-the-global-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Access to the Global Object (before ES5)

> If you need to access the global object without hard-coding the identifier window, you can do the following from any level of nested function scope:

```
var global = (function () {
    return this;
}());
```

> This way you can always get the global object, because inside functions that were invoked
>   as functions (that is, not as constrictors with new) this should always point to
>   the global object.

**This is actually no longer the case in ECMAScript 5 in strict mode,
so you have to adopt a different pattern when your code is in strict mode.**

> For example,
>   if you’re developing a library, you can wrap your library code in an immediate function
>   (discussed in Chapter 4) and then from the global scope, pass a reference to this as a
>   parameter to your immediate function.

### Access to the Global Object (after ES5)

> Commonly, the global object is passed as an argument to the immediate function so
>   that it’s accessible inside of the function without having to use window: this way makes
>   the code more interoperable in environments outside the browser:

```
(function (global) {
    // access the global object via `global`
}(this));
```

*“JavaScript Patterns, by Stoyan Stefanov
(O’Reilly). Copyright 2010 Yahoo!, Inc., 9780596806750.”*

Comment: That method may fail in the case that you're using a package manager that wraps your code in an additional closure (i.e. to prevent scope leakage).

Answer (score 8):

## Solution:

```
var global = Function('return this')();
```

Works in all Browsers, Engines, ES3, ES5, strict, nested scope, etc.

A slight variation will pass JSLINT:

```
var FN = Function, global = FN('return this')();
```

### Discussion

See [How to get the global object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277182/how-to-get-the-global-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Quite nice one as well, while trying to get it to work with jslint, I made a small modification var f = Function, global = f('return this')(); it gives no errors in jslint and correctly scopes the global ( yes I know that is just HIS recommendations, not set in stone, but I like making things pass the 'test' so to speak )

Comment: A modification of the second variant can eliminate the extraneous FN variable: `var global = (function(f){ return f('return this')(); })(Function);`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet from [Perfection Kills](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/), using global eval.

```
var root = (function () {
    return this || (0 || eval)('this');
}());
```

ECMA3, ECMA5, Strict mode, etc compatible, passes JSLint.

Comment: This is called **indirect eval**. There is a detailed article discussing this here: http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/

Comment: @NathanWall is there a way to get `(0, eval)('this')` to pass JSLint?

Comment: @AndrewHuth try `var globalEval = eval, global = globalEval('this');`