# Why does "use strict" break function assignment inside namespace to global scope?

Tags: javascript, strict, javascript-namespaces

I have library code does a simple function assignment. This function is accessed from the global scope.

When I add `"use strict"` at the beginning of the file, I get an error `TypeError: a is undefined`, on assignment to `a.b`.

```js
"use strict"; /* Remove this and 'a' is defined */
(function() {
  var a = this;
  a.b = function() {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'abc';
  };
})();
b();
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Why do I get this error considering that `var a` is declared on the previous line?

Comment: This has already been answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290086/javascript-use-strict-and-nicks-find-global-function

Comment: Yes, `a` is declared, but it is assigned to `this` which is undefined in strict mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Global Leakage
>
> There are a number of situations that could cause this to be bound to
>   the global object. For example, if you forget to provide the new
>   prefix when calling a constructor function, the constructor's this
>   will be bound unexpectedly to the global object, so instead of
>   initializing a new object, it will instead be silently tampering with
>   global variables. In these situations, strict mode will instead bind
>   this to undefined, which will cause the constructor to throw an
>   exception instead, allowing the error to be detected much sooner.

so you do not have **a** as **this**, but your **a** is **undefined**, so you cannot make **b** to **undefined**