# What is the value of `this` in Javascript outside a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have read a couple of articles on the web explaining `this` in Javascript. While the articles
have helped a lot, the behavior shown below is still unclear to me.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) it says:

> In the global execution context (outside of any `function`), this
>   refers to the global object, whether in strict mode or not.

If so, can someone please explain the behavior (noted in the comments) when the following code is
run with node.

```
console.log(this); // Returns an empty object: {}.
                  // Why does this line not return the global object.

var somefunc = function(name) {
    console.log(this);
}

somefunc(); // Returns the the global object. I think I understand this. The function is
           // invoked in a global context.

somefunc.call(this); // Again returns the empty object. Why?
```

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT (as requested by below by the moderators)**
**How is this question and the chosen answer different from the one linked above**

I think both the question and certainly the answer here is clearer than the one that is considered a duplicate. The answer here clarifies what node is doing by giving example code, which is more helpful.

Comment: This question has some interesting answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277182/how-to-get-the-global-object-in-javascript

Comment: Once the spelling is fixed, [I get the same result](http://jsbin.com/uyupal/1/edit) for all three variations.

Comment: I get `[object Window]` three times: http://jsfiddle.net/GzNXk/.

Comment: @Quentin The results are different even after fixing the spelling.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about this. It's not a good idea to use `this` outside a method anyway (ES5 strict mode forbids it too)

Comment: I am running the code with NodeJS. Could the behavior be different in browser and in Node? Can you please check it with Node?

Comment: @Curious2learn: If you're in a NodeJS module, then you're not in the global scope... rather your code is inside a function. For example, if you added `exports.foo = "bar";`, then you'll see that property and value on the local `this` as `this.foo; // "bar"`, but not on the global.

Comment: @CrazyTrain The above code is in a file called trial.js. There is nothing else in `trial.js` other than the above lines. I run it using `node trial.js` at the console. I am not very familiar with Node. I am using it mainly to run my javascript files in order to learn javascript. Regardless, it is still not clear why the behavior is different for the somefunc() and console.log(this).

Comment: @Curious2learn: By loading it that way, you're effectively running it as a module. This means that your code in `trial.js` is grafted into a function body, so it's as though you wrapped all your code in a function, and then executed that function. In a module, you get a variable named `exports`, which is used to exporting data for that module. The value of `this` in a module also points to that same exports object. That's why you get `{}`, because to start with, the `exports` object is just an empty object. If you do `console.log(this === exports)`, you'll get `true`.

Comment: ...when you do `somefunc()`, you've not explicitly defined a `this` value, so it automatically gets the global object. When you do `somefunc.call(this)`, now you've defined it with the enclosing `this` value, which as I described above, is the `this` value that was defined for that invisible function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first and the third showing of `this` should be identical in any case: in first case you just output the *current* value of `this`, and in the third you pass, again, the *current* value of `this` into `somefunc` (as a context argument).

But in the second, it's different: you call this function without assigning it any specific context, so `this` inside it points to a *global* object.

Why do you get an empty object as a result? One explanation is that your code is actually wrapped into some generic closure, like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/hc2vf/):

```
var sandbox = {};
(function() {
  console.log(this);      // 1
  var somefunc = function(name) {
     console.log(this);
  }
  somefunc();             // 2
  somefunc.call(this);    // 3
}).call(sandbox);
```

As this function is called in `sandbox` context, both `1` and `3` point to `sandbox` - that is an empty object. `2` is different: you don't supply *any* context to this function call, that's why *inside* the function (when it's called that way) `this` points to `global`.

And that's exactly what happens when you try to access `this` in a global context of Node module. I'll quote an explanation from [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nodejs/jsiOvCsHN7M):

> Node's modules are wrapped in a closure, which is evaluated in the
>   this-context of the `exports` object.  So, if you do `var a = 3`, then
>   it won't be added to `this`, `global`, or `exports`.  But, if you do `this.a
>   = 3` then it'll be added to `this` and `exports`.
>
> See: https://gist.github.com/788414

Note that it's quite different from using the code as it is within a browser. It's not wrapped in any closure, so all the calls - 1, 2 and 3 - are referring to the `global` object. And that's, as you know, `window`.

Comment: The question is asking why the three results are *different* (which they shouldn't be).

Comment: Updated my answer, though it's probably all cleared in the comments. )

Comment: Thanks. Your answer and CrazyTrain's comments were helpful.