# Why do we have to define "var console = window.console;" in some situation (such as running tests)?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I think it might be related to the test using PhantomJS, that the test will fail due to some `console.log` and I need to put a line:

```
var console = window.console;
```

at the top inside the IFFE, such as:

```
(function() {
    var console = window.console;

    // ...
}());
```

That is a bit strange.  First of all, isn't PhatomJS based on webkit, and I thought `console` and `console.log` are both defined.

Second, I thought if `window.console` is defined, and we set it using `var console = window.console;` then actually, if we don't defined the local `console`, when `console` is encountered, then the browser will automatically resolve to `window.console` because the global environment is `window`?

I think if the `console.log(...)` statements were replaced by `window.console.log(...)` then `var console = window.console;` won't be needed.

So why is the line `var console = window.console;` needed and what does it help solve?

Comment: it would say `console` is not defined and fail the test

Answer (score 0):

In the case that `window.console` is defined, the line has no effect.

In the case that `window.console` is *not* defined, the defines `console` as a valid identifier within the function scope. Without the line, the identifier `console` would produce a ReferenceError, but `window.console` simply gets you `undefined`.

Thus, the line defines `console` in the case that it's not already an extant identifier, or it uses the value of the global `console` in the case that it is an extant identifier.

Thus, we can conclude that in your test environment, `window.console` is not defined.

Comment: but why will `console.log(123)` fails without `var console = window.console;`

Comment: To be clear: does the console output actually work? is `console.log` also being defined anywhere?

Comment: `console.log()` doesn't work, unless if you use `window.console.log()`, or if you use `var console = window.console;` first

Comment: @動靜能量 Interesting. In that case, `window` must not be the global object here. You can check what the global object is with `var myglobal = Function('return this')();` ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3277182/710446)), and compare `myglobal == window`.

Comment: can't you just `console.log(this)` or check `this === window`

Comment: @動靜能量 Not if you're in strict mode -- in that case, `this` will be `null` (or `undefined`? one of those). Using the `Function` constructor with a string circumvents this issue and gets the real global object.