# JavaScript variable === undefined not working

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

I have the function:

```
isset = function(obj){
  alert(obj !== undefined);
 }
```

Then when I do `isset(defined_variable)` where `defined_variable` has been declared, the alert box shows **true** but when I do `isset(undefined_variable)` where `undefined_variable` has not been declared, the alert box does not show at all, while I expected the alert box to show **false**. What am I doing wrong? I have tried using `typeof` but the results are the same.

Comment: Using an undeclared variable throws an error in javascript, you can see it if you open your console (F12)

Comment: Show us the exact attempt you made using `typeof`.

Comment: The whole purpose of such function makes very little sense. There is a chance you're trying to solve the *original problem* in a very wrong way. So, if this is supposed to be a solution - it's highly recommended that you explained the real problem so that the community helped you to solve it *properly*

Comment: @torazaburo With `typeof`, what I did was `alert(typeof undefined_variable !== "undefined") `.

Comment: The problem is, that in order to be passed to the `isset` function without generating a `ReferenceError`, it must already be declared. Did you declare it? If you did, what you show should work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because there's a difference between undefined and undeclared.

```
var foo; // foo is undefined.
// bar is undeclared.

console.log(foo === undefined); // true
try {
  console.log(bar === undefined);
} catch (e) {
  console.error('I had an error!'); // gets invoked.
}

foo = 'something';
console.log(foo === undefined); // false
```

Comment: Why would you ever have an undeclared variable in your code?

Comment: Under some circumstances, such as when I'm using one javascript file for several pages. When using `document.getElementById('some-object-id')` for example, there are some pages that won't have `some-object-id`.

Comment: @TroubleZero When an id is not present in the DOM, `getElementById` returns `null`, isset does not check for `null` value it only checks for `undefined` values

Answer (score 1):

> but when I do isset(undefined_variable) where udefined_variable has
>   not been declared, the alert box does not show at all, while I
>   expected the alert box to show false

because it throws an error in your console (check your console) that this variable that you are comparing is not defined.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: 'c' is not defined

i tried with `isset( c )` and `c` was not declared first

Answer (score 1):

When you dereference an undeclared variable (meaning you try to use a symbol that was never wrote before), you get a `Reference error`.

---

There are several ways to deal with this, but you can't determine what are local variables in javascript. Thus, your problem can be solved dynamically only for global variables, or a given scope object.

### No functions could handle local scope dynamically.

---

You can prefix it with `window` if you are in a browser context (for more context see [this SO answer about global object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277182/how-to-get-the-global-object-in-javascript))

This would not modify your `isset` function code:

```
isset(window.undefined_variable)
```

There would be another way, which would need that `isset` function changes, but uses the same principle (still in browser context):

```
isset('undefined_variable_name_wrawppped_in_a_string')

function isset(name) {
    return name in window;
}
```

We can't really use `typeof` in `isset`, it's sad because it would be convenient since it doesn't throw a `Reference Error` when the variable was never declared. We could still use a form of eval to do it, but since I don't want us to go there, I won't implement it.

But now, what if you want to check several nested properties?

```
function isset (memoryPath, root) {
    var nodeNames = memoryPath.split('.');
    var expectedDepthReached = nodeNames.length;
    var depthReached = 0;
    var nodeName;
    var node = root;

    // we are gonna read it from left to right
    // using Array.prototype.pop()
    // reversing it will alow us to do so
    nodeNames.reverse();

    do {
        nodeName = nodeNames.pop();
        node = node[nodeName];

        if (node) {
            depthReached++;
        }
    } while (node);

    return depthReached === expectedDepthReached;
}
```

And an exemple:

```
window.myGlobals = {
    path: {
        to: {
            a: {
                variable: true
            }
        }
    }
};

isset('myGlobals.path.to.a.variable', window), // true
isset('myGlobals.path.foo', window) // false
```